# multiple where clause dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I pass two date range to my procedure then I select last date of each and every month as below

```
create procedure stcheck
@From_Date date,
@To_Date date
as
begin


declare @tmpTable table (dates date)
declare @startDate date = @From_Date
declare @endDate date = @To_Date

while @startDate <= @endDate

begin
    insert into @tmpTable (dates) values (@startDate)
    set @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate)
end

select max(dates) as [Last day] from @tmpTable as o
group by datepart(YEAR, dates), datepart(MONTH, dates)
```

If am getting result as follows

```
Last day
2017-01-31

2017-02-28

2017-03-31

2017-04-30
```

I need to pass some data to temporary table by using these date output

Ex :-

```
Insert #xyz

Select * from abcd where postdate <=’2017-01-31’
```

And my requirement is that these all dates should be automatically used and relevant data should pass to #table.

---

Hi expert . thank for your early reply.

In brief my requirement is as follows. Please help because I am new with sql.

Think,I have a table as ‘stock’ with in and out  stock transaction and stock

report can be taken as follows to any as at date

```
SELECT item ,SUM(InQty-OutQty)  FROM stock
WHERE TransDate <= @AsatDate 
GROUP BY item 
Having SUM(InQty-OutQty) > 0
```

If I need to get the each and every month end stock when I am passing the date range

from @From date= ‘2017/05/01’  to @AsatDate=‘2017/09/30’  .

The stock report result should be appear something like this.

[STOCK REPORT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p766g.jpg)

Please help what can be done?

NB:- it should be able to pass any date range when it is required.

Comment: Just a few items  1) I suspect SQL Server ... what version?  2)  Looping functions should be avoided.  3)  Sample source data and desired results would be more helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify the last part? How does that insert query relate to stored proc?

Comment: please see my further clarification

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming you want to run the stored procedure and insert data into the temp table `#xyz` (assumes temp table #xyz already exists):

```
insert into #xyz
exec stcheck @From_Date, @To_Date
```

*Now off on a little tangent:*

I'd also look at [table-valued functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) if you need parameterized, deterministic tabular output like this.  I agree with @John that you should avoid looping if possible.  One possible way to achieve this is instead of iterating day by day you use a pre-populated calendar table (stick say 50-100 years worth of future calendar dates in a table and use this in calculations - there are tons of examples of how to do this online). Another method is to use a recursive CTE or a numbers table, both outlined in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529860/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates).

Once your calendar dates are easily queryable, you can stick all this in a view or inline table-valued function and it will be super fast and much clearer.  If you regularly use "last day of month" as a filter criteria, you could even pre-calculate these as a column in your calendar table.  Here's what it could end up like:

```
insert into #xyz
select dbo.DatesBetween(@From_Date, @To_Date)
```

You could even use `dbo.DatesBetween(@From_Date, @To_Date)` directly in your query in place of the temp table, if it's only used once.

Comment: please see my further clarification