# What is the fastest way to populate table with dates after certain day?

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

Let's assume that we have the following input parameters:

- date [Date]
- period [Integer]

The task is the following: build the table which has two columns: *date* and *dayname*.

So, if we have `date` = `2018-07-12` and `period` = `3` the table should look like this:

```
date      |dayname 
-------------------
2018-07-12|THURSDAY
2018-07-13|FRIDAY
2018-07-14|SATURDAY
```

My solution is the following:

```
 select add_days(date, -1) into previousDay from "DUMMY";
 for i in 1..:period do
     select add_days(previousDay, i) into nextDay from "DUMMY";
     :result.insert((nextDay, dayname(nextDay));
 end for;
```

but I don't like the loop. I assume that it might be a problem in the performance if there are more complicated values that I want to put to result table.

*What would be the better solution to achieve the target?*

Comment: Try Googling two things, how to create a numbers table in hana (e.g. http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-numbers-table-function-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) and how to use a numbers table to create a list of dates (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529860/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates).  Using a numbers table is the usual method for best efficiency/ flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running through a loop and inserting values one by one is most certainly the slowest possible option to accomplish the task.

Instead, you could use SAP HANA's *time series* feature. 
With a statement like

```
SELECT to_date(GENERATED_PERIOD_START)
    FROM SERIES_GENERATE_TIMESTAMP('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '01.01.0001', '31.12.9999')
```

you could generate a bounded range of valid dates with a given interval length.

In my tests using this approach brought the time to insert a set of dates from ca. 9 minutes down to 7 seconds...

I've written about that some time ago [here](http://lbreddemann.org/fiddle-riddle-amazing-stuff-gets-faster-and-takes-less-space/) and [here](http://lbreddemann.org/quick-notes-during-a-fiddle-session/) if you want some more examples for that.
In those examples, I even included the use of *series tables* that allow for efficient compression of timestamp column values.

Comment: Yes, I can say that this looks very good, the only problem is that I need to use it in the procedure. In this case I use synonym and then I get the database error: 
feature not supported: field or table alias is not allowed as an input of table functions. Any ideas?

Comment: If you use XSA then it’s probably just a missing synonym to the table function. Create a new question for that problem and include your code and HANA version, I’d say.

Comment: Thanks, Lars, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Series Data functions include [SERIES_GENERATE_DATE](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-dates-table-using-sqlscript-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) which returns a set of values in date data format. So you don't have to bother to convert returned data into desired date format.

Here is a sample code

```
declare d int := 5;
declare dstart date := '01.01.2018';

SELECT generated_period_start FROM SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', :dstart, add_days(:dstart, :d));
```