# How to get 30 days from now from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am doing my project in MVC4 using c# and sql.. I have a table `MemberDetails` which contain table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberDetails] (
[Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Mem_FirstNA] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Mem_LastNA]  VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Mem_Occ]     VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Mem_DOB]     DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[Mem_Email]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 );
```

I just want to select the names and date of birth where whose birthday in next 30 days and I use the following query

```
SELECT 
    Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB 
FROM 
    MemberDetails 
WHERE 
    Mem_DOB >= getdate() - 1 AND Mem_DOB <= getdate() + 30
```

Is that correct, I got 0 item selected , I use the following table.

```
 1  Pal Software    08-03-1987 AM 12:00:00
 3  mn  Par Bussiness   19-10-1967 AM 12:00:00
 4  man George  Business    13-11-1956 AM 12:00:00
 5  Smi Kan Housewife   22-10-1980 AM 12:00:00
```

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: I know this is an ancient question but everyone has missed a key point: `Mem_DOB` contains dates from the 1900s and then people want to check `Mem_DOB >= getdate()`! Last century dates will never be greater than today's date.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this...
    <del>SELECT 
        Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB 
    FROM 
        MemberDetails 
    WHERE 
        ltrim(str(year(GETDATE()))) + '-' + ltrim(str(month(Mem_DOB))) + '-' +  ltrim(str(day(Mem_DOB))) >= getdate() - 1 AND ltrim(str(year(GETDATE()))) + '-' + ltrim(str(month(Mem_DOB))) + '-' +  ltrim(str(day(Mem_DOB))) <= getdate() + 30</del>

EDIT: The comments for this answer have rightly pointed out that it will not work if the current year is a leap year. So this update. The list of dates can be more efficiently generated by using [Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function)

```
Select Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB from MemberDetails m, (
Select datepart(dd,getdate()) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate()) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 1) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 1) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 2) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 2) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 3) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 3) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 4) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 4) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 5) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 5) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 6) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 6) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 7) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 7) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 8) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 8) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 9) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 9) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 10) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 10) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 11) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 11) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 12) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 12) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 13) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 13) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 14) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 14) as m
union
Select datepart(dd,getdate() + 15) as d,  datepart(mm,getdate() + 15) as m
)X
where   
datepart(dd, m.Mem_DOB) = x.d and datepart(mm, m.Mem_DOB) = x.m
```

If you are downvoting, please comment why.

Comment: Great, but do consider the efficiency. I have not tested how efficient it is.

Comment: ya this query is taken the date in january

Comment: This is the **wrong** way to do this. If you find yourself converting dates to strings, you're doing something very wrong. It's the slowest way to do the conversion, and thanks to possible different database collations/operating system date formats, it's an way to introduce bugs into the process.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I know and that is why I have specifically mentioned in my comment that I have not tested its efficiency. But at that moment this is what came to my mind and as this answer is the accepted one I will update the answer with a efficient query.

Comment: Even ignoring efficiency and formatting for a moment, this technique fails when attempting to update a leap day birthday into a common (non-leap) year.

Comment: @pilcrow - Updated the answer, comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Updated

```
SELECT 
    Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB 
FROM 
    MemberDetails 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, Mem_DOB, GETDATE()), Mem_DOB)) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

Comment: I don't think this query will work. `Mem_DOB` is in the past, and `getdate()` is today. How will they ever be equal? Example: say dob `18-Oct-1980`, how will it match with `dateadd(day, -n, getdate())`? Because `getdate()` will return `2013`.

Comment: @unlimit, you're right. I forget to set current year to date of birth

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        SELECT 
           Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB
        FROM 
             MemberDetails 
       WHERE DAYOFYEAR(Mem_DOB)-DAYOFYEAR(getdate())<=30
```

Comment: `DAYOFYEAR`? Neat, did not think of it.

Comment: Fails at year boundaries.  What happens if DOB := '1990-01-01' and getdate() == '2013-12-31' ?  (I gave you +1 in haste, however, so enjoy it! :))

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB 
FROM 
    MemberDetails 
WHERE 
    Mem_DOB >= Cast(current_timestamp As Date) AND Mem_DOB < DATEADD(d, 30, Cast(current_timestamp As Date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work. Between usage was removed based on comments. 
Will work for January birth dates as well

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
    SET @now = GETDATE()

 SELECT Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB
   FROM MemberDetails
  WHERE 
   CASE WHEN month(Mem_DOB) = 1
   THEN DATEADD(YY, YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 30, DATEADD(m,  month(@now) - 1, DAY(@now) - 1))) - 1900, DATEADD(m,  month(Mem_DOB) - 1, DAY(Mem_DOB) - 1))
   ELSE DATEADD(m,  month(Mem_DOB) - 1, DAY(Mem_DOB) - 1)
    END
      > DATEADD(m,  month(@now) - 1, DAY(@now) - 1) 
    AND 
   CASE WHEN month(Mem_DOB) = 1
   THEN DATEADD(YY, YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 30, DATEADD(m,  month(@now) - 1, DAY(@now) - 1))) - 1900, DATEADD(m,  month(Mem_DOB) - 1, DAY(Mem_DOB) - 1))
   ELSE DATEADD(m,  month(Mem_DOB) - 1, DAY(Mem_DOB) - 1)
    END
      < DATEADD(DAY, 30, DATEADD(m,  month(@now) - 1, DAY(@now) - 1))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Er, Please don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time types, [especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Personally, `BETWEEN` should be removed from all statements (and the standard)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    Mem_FirstNA, Mem_LastNA, Mem_DOB 
FROM 
    MemberDetails 
WHERE 
    WHERE DATEPART(mm,Mem_DOB) BETWEEN DATEPART(mm,getDate()) AND DATEPART(mm,getDate())+1;
```

Comment: Agarwal: still i got 0 rows selected

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. You will have to consider the current year.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal: Is any date format problem in my database and query

Comment: Run query in Query Editor, then tell me what is the output.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal - `Mem_DOB` is in the past, and `getdate()` is today. How will they ever be equal? Example: say dob `18-Oct-1980`, how will it match with `dateadd(day, -n, getdate())`? Because `getdate()` will return `2013`.

Answer (score 0):

why not use this where clause:

```
WHERE MEM_DOB BETWEEN GETDATE()-1 AND GETDATE()+30
```

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time types, [especially in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).