# Extracting Days from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here a date range from  
**"1/27/2014" - Start** 
**"1/31/2014" - End**

Note:

**On Figure 1** - that is the data from SQL
**On Figure 2** - that is how I want may data to be extracted

How can I do this using SQL query?
Is this possible?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use (MSSQL,MySQL,Oracle,...)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE
SET @startDate = '1/27/2014'
SET @endDate = '1/31/2014'
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)
SELECT Date from dates
```

## [See it live](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14520)

Comment: Hi, I have updates. Can you check if this is possible also. Thanks

Comment: hmm.. Update is incorrect ! 1/29/2014 should be girl.. and i dont think thers way to get in sql server?

Comment: hi @vijaykumar can you check out on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569473/pivotting-date-range-using-sql

Comment: hi @vijaykumar. i have a question here. can I use this dates inside "IN" clause. EX: select * from table where date in (select dates from dates)

Comment: Yes! But you need to keep syntax correct!y `IN operator`

Comment: what if im using it in pivot can i still use this?

Comment: LIKE THIS: count(splitdates)
 for PivotDate in (select date from dates)