# Splitting/Pivot Data from a Date Range using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hi I have a problem with regarding on split/pivot dates

Here is my query

```
select Name
     , Start
     , End 
  from Employees 
 where Start >= '1/27/2014' 
   and End <= '1/31/2014'
```

And Sample Data would be like this

[image]

What I want to do is to split/pivot all data by date range like this

[image]

But I don't know how can i do this and if it is possible? 
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like that is pivoting and not splitting. If yes, then please change your title and tag list to show pivoting. Pivoting means converting a column to a row and vice versa.

Comment: It is more unpivot then pivot;)

Comment: What's the type of `Start` and `End`?  If it's a timestamp, you probably want [a look at this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Note that this still applies to MySQL anyways, given that timestamps can have differing sets of millisecond precision.

Comment: A good solution here: [Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to generate all the dates. i did this here by using a cte. i then join this date range with your data and receive the sought result.

```
with DateRange AS
(
    SELECT CAST('1/27/2014' as DATEtime) DateValue
     UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(dd,1,DateValue)
      FROM DateRange
     WHERE dateadd(dd,1,DateValue) <= CAST('3/31/2014' as datetime)
)
select name
     , DateValue
  from Employees
  join DateRange
    on start <= DateValue
   and [end] >= datevalue
 order by 
       name
     , DateValue
```

---

**outdated after your updated question**
i would go about it with a simple union:

```
select Name
     , Start
  from Employees 
 where Start >= '1/27/2014' 
   and End <= '1/31/2014'
 union all
select Name
     , End
  from Employees 
 where Start >= '1/27/2014' 
   and End <= '1/31/2014'
 order by
       Name
```

Comment: i tried this one, but the date from january 28 to 30 should be included

Comment: i got an error on interval and curdate(). The error says that there is no built in function

Comment: hi @brett, can you try this using sql server 2008

Comment: try not to waste people's time by asking and tagging your questions properly from the beginning. this is the last time i updated this question

Comment: It works.. Thanks you so much. I'm stack here for 2 days already. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the table as -

```
USE `Test`;
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`Tbl_Sample_Data` (
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,    
  `Start` DATETIME NULL ,
  `End` DATETIME NULL );
```

Insert rows using -

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`tbl_sample_data`
(`End`,
`Name`,
`Start`)
VALUES
(
'PutEndDateHere',
'PutNameHere',
'PutStartDateHere'
);
```

Here, dates should be in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, otherwise you get error 1292.

Use this query to get what you want.

```
SELECT `Name`,'Start' AS colName, `Start` AS value FROM test.tbl_sample_data
UNION ALL
SELECT `Name`,'End' AS colName, `End` AS value FROM test.tbl_sample_data
ORDER BY `Name` ASC
```

Note that column names whose name is the same as a keyword must be enclosed in backticks. Eg. Example Name. Otherwise, you get error.