# StartDate and EndDate columns convert to one Date column with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am starting with a table that looks similar to this:

```
Name    |   StartDate   |   EndDate
------------------------------------
Bob     |   5/1/2017    |   5/3/2017
Jeff    |   6/1/2017    |   6/1/2017  
Bob     |   7/8/2017    |   7/10/2017
```

And I would like it to end up like this:

```
Name    |   Date
------------------------------------
Bob     |   5/1/2017    
Bob     |   5/2/2017    
Bob     |   5/3/2017
Jeff    |   6/1/2017
Bob     |   7/8/2017    
Bob     |   7/9/2017    
Bob     |   7/10/2017
```

Comment: I would look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function

then join back to that table to get everything between startdate and enddate for each name.. just a suggested approach

This is assuming you don't already have access to a date table of some sort..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select name, StartDate, EndDate
      from t
      union all
      select name, dateadd(day, 1, StartDate), EndDate
      from cte
      where StartDate < EndDate
     )
select name, StartDate as dte
from cte;
```

As written, this works for about 100 days.  If you need more, just add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the query.