# SQL list recurring dates between two dates with end date as next start date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is similar to this 
[Get a list of dates between two dates using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function)

using this code for 10 days recurring:

```
Declare @startDate datetime
Declare @endDate datetime


set @startDate= '03/01/2019 12:00:00'
set @endDate = '04/30/2019 12:00:00'


 ;WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT CAST(@startDate AS DATETIME) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 10
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue + 10 < @endDate - 1
)

SELECT  DateValue
FROM    mycte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I get the ff result:

```
2019-03-20 12:00:00.000
2019-03-30 12:00:00.000
2019-04-09 12:00:00.000
2019-04-19 12:00:00.000
```

but I want the result to be :

```
2019-03-20 12:00:00.000
2019-03-30 12:00:00.000
2019-03-31 12:00:00.000
2019-04-09 12:00:00.000
2019-04-10 12:00:00.000
2019-04-20 12:00:00.000
2019-04-21 12:00:00.000
2019-04-30 12:00:00.000
```

Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: Why do you Apr 9th and 10th and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the problem rather arcane, but this seems to do what you want:

```
set @startDate= '2019-03-10 12:00:00';
set @endDate = '2019-04-30 12:00:00';


WITH mycte AS (
       SELECT CAST(@startDate AS DATETIME) as DateValue
       UNION ALL
       SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, EOMONTH(DateValue)) + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(TIME, DateValue))
       FROM  mycte  
       WHERE MONTH(DateValue + 10) <> MONTH(DateValue) AND
             CONVERT(DATE, DATEVALUE) <> CONVERT(DATE, EOMONTH(DateValue)) AND
             DateValue < @endDate
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DateValue + 10
       FROM mycte
       WHERE DateValue + 10 < @endDate
      )
SELECT DISTINCT DateValue
FROM mycte
ORDER BY DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b54ae56fca7c8978343a43287d540bb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, works well. Another question, what if I want to expand the end date to 2019-10-01? This breaks after the first month.

Comment: @dragon_heart . . . You should ask another question.  The one you asked here has been answered.