# Query in sql involving joins of two table

Tags: sql, mysql

**EDIT 2**

I  have two tables `reports` and `holidays`.

`reports`: `(username varchar(30),activity varchar(30),hours int(3),report_date date)`

`holidays`: `(holiday_name varchar(30), holiday_date date)`

`select * from reports`  gives

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
| username |  activity |  hours  |   date     |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
| prasoon  |   testing |    3    | 2009-01-01 |
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-03 |
| gautam   |   coding  |    1    | 2009-01-04 |  
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-06 |
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-10 |
| gautam   |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-10 |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

`select * from holidays` gives

```
+--------------+---------------+  
| holiday_name |  holiday_date |
+--------------+---------------+ 
| Diwali       |   2009-01-02  |
| Holi         |   2009-01-05  |  
+--------------+---------------+
```

**EDIT**

When I used the following query

```
 SELECT dates.date AS date,
  CASE 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(reports.activity, 'Absent') 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NOT NULL and reports.activity IS NOT NULL THEN  reports.activity
  ELSE ''
    END 
  AS activity,
  CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(reports.hours, 'Absent')
    WHEN holiday_name IS NOT NULL and reports.hours IS NOT NULL THEN reports.hours
    ELSE ''
    END 
  AS hours,
  CASE 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(holidays.holiday_name, '')
    ELSE holidays.holiday_name
    END 
  AS holiday_name
  FROM dates 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON dates.date = reports.date 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays ON dates.date = holidays.holiday_date
  where reports.username='gautam' and dates.date>='2009-01-01' and dates.date<='2009-01-09';
```

I got the following output

```
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |  date    |  activity |  hours  |   holiday  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |2009-01-04|   coding  |    1    |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

but I expected this

```
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |  date    |  activity |  hours  |   holiday  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |2009-01-01|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-02|           |         | Diwali     |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-03|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-04|  Coding   |   1     |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-05|           |         | Holi       |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-06|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-07|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-08|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-09|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

How can I modify the above query to get the desired output(for a particular user (gautam in this case))?

Comment: You keep changing your question! Open a new question, please. To do something like this, you'll need nested selects (and put the where clause with the user into the nested select). You also don't need a CASE bit for the 'holiday' column.

Comment: I've also changed my answer below to answer your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:** Here's the answer to your new question. Note that you were using the CASE statements incorrectly - `COALESCE(reports.activity, 'Absent')` will return `reports.activity` if it is not null, and `'Absent'` if it is.

First you need a table `dates` with the dates you want to check, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (date date);
```

and then fill it manually for now:

```
date      
----------
2009-01-01
2009-01-02
2009-01-03
2009-01-04
2009-01-05
2009-01-06
2009-01-07
2009-01-08
2009-01-09
2009-01-10
```

This can be created procedurally, but that's another topic entirely.

Here's the query, using left outer joins and a nested select:

```
SELECT dates.date AS date,
CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(user_reports.activity, 'Absent')
 ELSE '' END AS activity,
CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(user_reports.hours, 'Absent')
 ELSE '' END AS hours,
COALESCE(holidays.holiday_name, '') AS holiday_name
FROM dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reports.username='guatam') AS user_reports
 ON dates.date = user_reports.report_date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays ON dates.date = holidays.holiday_date
WHERE dates.date>='2009-01-01' and dates.date<='2009-01-09';
```

Which returns:

```
date        activity    hours       holiday_name
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------
2009-01-01  Absent      Absent                  
2009-01-02                          Diwali      
2009-01-03  Absent      Absent                  
2009-01-04  coding      1                       
2009-01-05                          Holi        
2009-01-06  Absent      Absent                  
2009-01-07  Absent      Absent                  
2009-01-08  Absent      Absent                  
2009-01-09  Absent      Absent
```

But the real problem is that you are doing something that's very poor practice - **you're using SQL to format your information. This is bad!** You should be using it only to retrieve your information, and then format it with HTML or whatever you're pulling the data into. Your select should be a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE username='guatam'
 AND date>='2009-01-01' AND date<='2009-01-9'
```

And a separate one for the holidays, if you need it:

```
SELECT * from holidays
```

And then use that information as you need.

Comment: I'm new to MySQL and see that `COALESCE()` works like `ISNULL()`in MSSQL, am I right? TIO

Comment: Not sure about ISNULL. And sorry, forgot to add that you need a table dates to represent the date range. Will add to the answer above

Comment: similar, but more succinct and more useful.  You can have any number of values in a coalesce() check, not just two.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates for some hints on how you can make the list of dates that you need as well.  Use the function described there to create a temporary table, then join that as  colinmarc describes above.

Comment: See my answer below for how to do colinmarc's final step.

Comment: @EI Yobo: I am getting 'NULL' instead of 'Absent', why?

Comment: So maybe it's better to use `IFNULL()` instead of `COALESCE()` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `IFNULL()` just returns a 0 or 1, which we would have to then test. in this case `COALESCE()` works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> fill in the missing dates...with "On
>   leave"

You can accomplish the remainder of your request by performing a pair of [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) to a table populated with a list of dates in the desired date range.

Comment: "Missing dates" implies the dates which are neither present in `reports` table nor in `holidays` table...

Comment: Your answer should have been a comment. :)

Comment: If you perform the outer join to the holidays table first, you can then use a CASE statement to determine whether the `activity` and `hours` columns are filled from the `reports` table or the string "Absent"

Comment: I tried to do what you said but didn't succeed. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of colinmarc's answer above, just to show how you can avoid having "Absent" in there when it's a holiday.  Otherwise the answer is much the same as his.

```
SELECT
    d.adate AS `date`,
    CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN coalesce(activity, 'Absent') 
    ELSE '' END AS activity,
    CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN coalesce(hours, 'Absent') 
    ELSE '' END AS activity,
    coalesce(holiday_name, '')
FROM (
    SELECT holiday_date AS adate FROM holidays
    UNION
    SELECT report_date AS adate FROM reports
) d
LEFT JOIN reports r ON (d.adate = r.report_date)
LEFT JOIN holidays h ON (d.adate = h.holiday_date)
ORDER BY adate ASC
```

Comment: Note that this only shows the dates where something happened; replace the subselect with the union with a table with all the dates in instead (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) and you can show all the dates instead.

Comment: @EI Yobo: I am getting `NULL` instead of `Absent`, why?

Comment: Satish, what would you like to have?  The bits that two lines that start with "ELSE NULL END" can be changed to be whatever you like, e.g. "ELSE 'Holiday' END" would give you Holiday instead of Absent.

Comment: If you just want it to be empty, change it to be "ELSE '' END" instead of "ELSE NULL END".

Comment: I've made this change for you in my answer.

Comment: You don't need to Coalesce `holiday_name`... the outer join will leave that blank.

Comment: Satish mentioned in his question that he didn't like the NULLs, so I modified the query to give him empty strings instead, as I did in the case statements.