# MySQL Dates between Dates

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I am wondering if there is a way, in MySQL 4.1+, to query the specific dates between date ranges in my records?

For a quick example, I have two records with datetime ranges, like

```
ID  |  Activity  |  Start Date         | End Date

1      Closed       1/1/11 11:00:00      1/4/11 11:00:00

2      Open         1/15/11 10:00:00     1/19/11 09:00:00
```

What I want to know is, is there a way I can get the dates between the "Start Date" and "End Date" for each of these records? Like so:

1/2/11, 1/3/11

And

1/16/11, 1/17/11, 1/18/11

Or at least a way to get close to that and use PHP to finish the rest of the way? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the date?  Get records between them, or just the dates themselves between start and end?

Comment: This is all on one table. I would like to get the day, month, year at the very least. I actually want to exclude the days themselves--since the event occurs by the hour, the day itself is not effected by the event (like, if we close up for 6 hours one day, but are open for the first 4 hours of that day.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jordan,

This is not directly possible with MySQL 4. And i think this logic should not be put in your database layer.

There is however a question on StackOverflow that relates to your problem and the solution is a stored procedure (but for that you need mysql 5). View it here: [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

I found a not ready to use, but sensible approach to your problem in PHP at this web-page:
http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-using-php-code/

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I don't mind using a PHP solution, but I want to get the most out of the query if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This might sole your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE start_date > '2011-01-01' AND end_date < '2011-01-04'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implimented this in my own mysql queries before.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE some_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```