# Select Date Between Two Columns

Tags: sql

I need a query in SQL.
If I have two columns `STARTDATE` and `END_DATE`.
I want to select a all rows where a date falls between these two dates.

> e.g.: startdate = 1/1/2011 AND enddate = 2/2/2011.

Comment: Do you mean you need one row for each of the individual dates between start and end in the result set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of dates between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: If this is MySQL. If not, sorry for the quick dupe close vote :)

Comment: Too all the close voters, how is this not a real question? It is clear as glass that the OP wants to do `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ? BETWEEN startdate AND enddate`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE '2011-01-01' BETWEEN table1.startdate AND table1.enddate
```

Replace the explicit date either with `now()` or a parameter or whatever.

If the enddate is **not** defined as `NOT NULL` you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE '2011-01-01' BETWEEN table1.startdate AND COALESCE(table1.enddate, NOW())
```

See: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-coalesce.html

Comment: +1 - But I would change enddate to `COALESCE(enddate,now())`

Comment: If the `enddate` is defined as NOT NULL, good suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Does this help you ?

```
select * 
from table 
where START_DATE < NOW() AND END_DATE > NOW()
```

Depending on the database, use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or TODAY()

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
select *
from mytable
where start_date >= '01/01/2011'
and end_date <= '02/01/2011'
```

Until you do more to clarify your question, it's hard for us to provide better answers.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT
Count (DISTINCT id)
FROM
Table
WHERE
rqmnt_start_date::TIMESTAMP >= '27/01/2022'
and rqmnt_end_date::TIMESTAMP <= '30/11/2022'**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).