# How i can Insert Dates in the table from given date Ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have Table Fields (Columns) like

```
ID
DATE
```

I want to insert the rows in above table in between date ranges

For Example:

If I given the date Range like 23/1/2014 to 25/1/2014

then row insertion result should be like this

```
   ID   |   DATES   

    1   |   23/1/2014

    2   |   24/1/2014

    3   |   25/1/2014
```

**please provide me the solution in the form of Query not Stored procedure/Function**

Comment: which programming language you are using..?

Comment: i am using java but i want to this insertion through only sql query...

Comment: I don't think it's possible in MySQL.

Comment: You must have to use Stored Procedure or Function for this.

Comment: @YograjSudewad Look the solution of your problem [How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616)

Comment: Thank you @DoNotArrestMe.....its needful for me. Please Post your answer in this Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use generated range in one query then look to the solution of your problem [How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this equivalent in MySQL. This works in SQL Serever but not tried in MySQL

```
Declare @date table(autoid int IDENTITY(1, 1),d date)
Declare @d datetime

set @d='20140123'

While @d<='20140125'
Begin
    Insert into @date values (@d)
    set @d=@d+1
End
Select autoid ,d as DateCol from @date
```

Comment: @Damith OP want to not use **Stored procedure/Function**

Comment: This is just a sql query not a Sp or function. But you have to convert     this into mysql.

Comment: @Damith It is not one query. OP want to use one query. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This Query will help to get all dates in between range. with that you can insert it in your table:

```
    select * from (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

Comment: this is not the exact ans but with this you can do it. you need to make sub query with these query.

Comment: This answer is already give by @DoNotArrestMe in question comments.