# How to insert all dates in 2015 in Date field?

Tags: sql-server, date

I am using SQL Server and have a table (Table_Date) with a 'date' field. I want to insert all 2015 dates in this field.

It should have 365 distinct rows, 1 row for each day of 2015.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can Insert Dates in the table from given date Ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299773/how-i-can-insert-dates-in-the-table-from-given-date-ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
CREATE TABLE #nums(num INT);
INSERT INTO #nums VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

WITH cteDays AS
(
    SELECT 100*d100.num + 10*d10.num + d1.num AS YearDay
    FROM       #nums AS d1
    CROSS JOIN #nums AS d10
    CROSS JOIN #nums AS d100
    WHERE d100.num <=3
)
SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME) + YearDay AS YearDate
FROM    cteDays
WHERE   YEAR(CAST( CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME) + YearDay AS DATETIME)) = 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is with a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2015-01-01' as date) as thedate
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, thedate)
      from dates
      where thedate < '2015-12-31'
     )
select *
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

An alternative is to use a table that has at least 365 rows.  `master..spt_values` is often used for this purpose:

```
select dateadd(day, seqnum - 1, '2015-01-01')
from (select row_number() over (order by ()) as seqnum
      from master..spt_values
     ) t
where seqnum <= 365;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for suggesting two solutions for my problem. I tried to run the recursive CTE but it gave the following error. Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Sam . . . I left the type out of the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work as well:

```
declare @count int = 0

while (@count < 365)
begin
    --make this the insert
    select DATEADD(DD, @count, getdate())
    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

Not sure what context this will applied to though...  This is very basic, but if this is a one-time event it won't matter.