# Mysql if not exists return 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like this :

```
date           data
01-01-2005       10 |
02-01-2005       11|
03-01-2005       13|
07-01-2005       20|
```

How i can list like below

```
date           data:
01-01-2005       10|
02-01-2005       11|
03-01-2005       13|
04-01-2005       0|
05-01-2005       0|
06-01-2005       0|
07-01-2005       20|
```

EDIT: i use a calendar table like this:

```
date:
01-01-2005 for all 365 days.
```

this my best opinion but it is not working :

```
SELECT c.steps, IFNULL(c.steps, 0) value, r.calendar_date
  FROM log_activities c
  LEFT JOIN calendar r
    ON (r.calendar_date = c.date_logged)
 WHERE email = 'a@mail.com'
 ORDER BY c.date_logged DESC
```

Comment: By writing a query. Show us what query you've tried.

Comment: Search for calendar table.Also add a query,no matter how wrong.Show some effort.

Comment: Updated.Please comment. @Mihai

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query

Comment: I would try what @Mihai linked and I would also think about how you are adding data to your table. You should think about seeding every day even if it is to have a 0 amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.steps, IFNULL(c.steps, 0) value, r.calendar_date
  FROM log_activities c
 right JOIN calendar r
    ON r.calendar_date = c.date_logged
 WHERE email = 'a@mail.com'
   and substr(r.calendar_date, 4, 2) = '01'
   and r.calendar_date between
       (select min(date_logged) from log_activities) and
       (select max(date_logged) from log_activities)
 ORDER BY c.date_logged DESC
```

Comment: Can you give example data? Are you sure that the 1st of each month is indeed on the calendar table? (the months you want to show up, but which don't have records on the log). Also I don't know if your criteria on that email address was an example ('a@mail.com') but you would get rid of that if it is.

Comment: yes i change email address and i delete substr then i got same result . But this result still is missing.(not add any 0's date)

Comment: I'd have to see the calendar table. The query should show all dates in the calendar table (only those on the first of the month) and if the same date is on the log_activities table, it should show the applicable data. The fact that no rows come back suggests that the calendar table does not contain dates in the range.

Comment: yes i have some rows in this range. my calendar table have only one row and like this:
01-01-2005
02-01-2005
03-01-2005
..
...
27-12-2006

Comment: @erdinc I just loaded some sample data to test the query here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3766/2/0 and it seems to work as expected, I would double check the source data.