# How can get all dates between two dates in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

How can get all dates between two dates in sqlite?

date from : 2014-05-01
date to : 2014-05-06

Results in rows :

2014-05-01
2014-05-02
 
2014-05-03
 
2014-05-04
 
2014-05-05
 
2014-05-06

Found same scenario but it has been done in MySQL. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with that approach? Also, why do you need to do it in SQL - a general-purpose programming language is likely better for such work.

Answer (score 0):

can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where Date between fromDate and toDate
```

give your required value to `fromDate` and `toDate` parameters.

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  datecol  BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-06'
```