# Populate empty dates

Tags: mysql

My database table structure is something like

```
stats_id stats_date   stats_visitors stats_visits
1        2015-08-01   10             20
2        2015-08-03   12             21
3        2015-08-04   14             24
4        2015-08-07   15             21
```

What is the easiest way to add empty stats date. For example I am missing 2015-08-02 so it should be:

```
stats_id stats_date   stats_visitors stats_visits
1        2015-08-01   10             20
5        2015-08-02   0              0
2        2015-08-03   12             21
3        2015-08-04   14             24
6        2015-08-05   0              0
7        2015-08-06   0              0
4        2015-08-07   15             21
```

I can check every day if it has data and populate but when I have over 10K rows its not really a good idea. If I use a check for each day I will generate over 10k queries.

Is there an easy way I can do this?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Is `stats_id` `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Comment: Yes @Praveen, its AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out.

```
insert into Table1 select '',selected_date,'0','0' from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between (select min(stats_date) from Table1) and (select max(stats_date) from Table1) and selected_date not in (select stats_date from Table1);
```

The `select adddate` part of the query will give you all the dates in between the max and min date of your data set, and using `not in` we get only those dates which does not exist in your data set.

Since you have auto incrementing id field, you can pass an empty string in your select query and it will ignore this and insert the auto-incremented value.

Source of select all dates query: [How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
insert into tbl(stats_date, stats_visitors, stats_visits)
select in_date, 0, 0
from (
    SELECT 
        @date := DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS in_date
    from
        (SELECT @date := min(stats_date) from tbl) r CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 0  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) a CROSS JOIN  
        (SELECT 0  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) b CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT 0  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) c CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT 0  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) d CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT 0  UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) e
    where @date < (select max(stats_date) from tbl)
) t
where in_date not in (select stats_date from tbl);
```

Here the sub-query will give dates between the `min(stats_date)` and `max(stats_date)`.

`Cross join` will give maximum of `1024` rows( i.e. `4 power 5`)
If your table have more then `1024` dates between `min and max date`, then add more `cross join` or more `union all`.