# MySQL Query that adds blanks to fill the gaps

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a MySQL query that given a specified date it will return the last 7 days of results, but in the MySQL table there could be blanks.

So the table could look like this

tblMyData

```
TestDate    |   val1   |   val2 
2014-07-10  |   20     |   30 
2014-07-09  |   10     |   10
2014-07-07  |   11     |   22
2014-07-04  |    9     |   45
```

However my query would need to fill in the blanks so my results would look like this

```
TestDate    |   val1   |   val2 
2014-07-10  |   20     |   30 
2014-07-09  |   10     |   10
2014-07-08  |    0     |    0     <<-- Added by the query
2014-07-07  |   11     |   22
2014-07-06  |    0     |    0     <<-- Added by the query
2014-07-05  |    0     |    0     <<-- Added by the query
2014-07-04  |    9     |   45
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to generate the dates with a subquery, and then join this subquery with your table.

If you only need the last 7 days then you can try with this:

```
select d.testdate, coalesce(t.val1,0), coalesce(t.val2,0)
from
  (select current_date as testdate
   union all select current_date - interval 1 day
   union all select current_date - interval 2 day
   union all select current_date - interval 3 day
   union all select current_date - interval 4 day
   union all select current_date - interval 5 day
   union all select current_date - interval 6 day) d
  left join tblMyData t
  on d.testdate = t.testdate
```

if instead of the current_date, you want the last 7 days in the table, then your query can be like this:

```
select m.m - interval d day, coalesce(t.val1,0), coalesce(t.val2,0)
from
  (select max(testdate) as m from tblMyData) m
  cross join
  (select 0 as d
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6) d
  left join tblMyData t
  on m.m - interval d day = t.testdate
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d930/2).

Comment: For an alternative approach to populating a subquery with a set of dates (aliased as `d` in the above answer), see this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query.  This may be desired if your possible range of dates far exceeds 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the SEQUENCE ENGINE you can do it like this.
This Sample is for the last 100 day, but you can change it.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tblMyData
SELECT DATE(now() - INTERVAL seq DAY),0,0 FROM seq_0_to_100;
```