# Need help in sql query to convert comma seperated values from a column in to rows

Tags: mysql, sql

(converted actaul data into example data)
This is my table-

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (

  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `col2` text,
  )
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1129311 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> col1   col2
>
> 1        abc,xyx,lmn

Need help in sql query to get output in below format

```
col1 col2

1       abc

1       xyz

1       lmn
```

tried below but did not worked

```
SELECT A.col1,

 Split.a.value(',', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS STRING

  FROM (SELECT sources, CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(col2, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS STRING 

  FROM table1) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

  WHERE A.col1=1;
```

Comment: You can follow this link and its already mark as duplicate by @Drew with same link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows. I am deleting my answer

Comment: @BharatPatidar yeah `fthiella` had a count of 5 limit. My comment under his showed a 4k count trick here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39696971

Comment: Thanks for help!  
Below queries worked-  
SELECT  
  table.col1,  
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.col2, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) NAME  
FROM  
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2  
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5   UNION ALL SELECT 6) numbers INNER JOIN org  
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(table1.col2)  
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(table1.col2, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1  
     WHERE table1.col1 IN (1)  
ORDER BY  
  col1, n;

Comment: and in oracle-------Oracle-
   SELECT a.col1,
       regexp_substr(a.col2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 1) a  
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(a.col2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL  
       AND PRIOR a.col2 = a.col2  
       AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;