# Insert every date of the year mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to add every date of the year into my database table. How could I to do that ?

I was looking in google but there is no clue.

Please help me with some insert query to do that.

This is my table structure.

```
id | date
---------
1 | 2017-01-01
```

Comment: check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated after question clarified.

Here is an updated version, try this out.  For the while loop to work you need to create it as a stored procedure.  Create the stored procedure like so

```
DELIMITER $$

create PROCEDURE insert_year_dates() 
BEGIN 
    SET @t_current = NOW(); 
    SET @t_end = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR); 
    WHILE(@t_current< @t_end) DO 
        INSERT INTO day (day) VALUES (@t_current); 
        SET @t_current = DATE_ADD(@t_current, INTERVAL 1 DAY); 
    END WHILE; 
END;
```

Then call that stored procedure using

```
CALL insert_year_dates()
```

Comment: could you give me complete insert query with your answer and I want date format like this `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: I've updated the answer, but as I said, without know what your table structure is I can't give you an exact query.

Comment: I just edited my questions with table structure and it just simpe table with field `id` and `date`

Comment: Take my answer and replace `table` with your table name and replace `field` with your field name.

Comment: I got this error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEAR, 1))' at line 1`

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: INSERT INTO `day` (`date`) VALUES (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), YEAR, 1))

Comment: Are you sure `DATE_ADD(NOW(), YEAR, 1)` is valid? I only know `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer.  I confused my MySQL syntax with my Sql Server syntax.  I've corrected it.

Comment: with `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` there is no error message but it just insert today's date in 2018 not all date in one year. @t.niese

Comment: If you run `SELECT NOW();  SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);` what do you get?

Comment: if I run `SELECT NOW();` I got `2017-01-27 15:29:03` and if I run `SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);` I got `2018-01-27 15:29:58`

Comment: Well there you go. the query I gave you should work as expected.  The second one you ran returns a value 1 year into the future.  That's exactly what the query you're trying to run is inserting.

Comment: and what is the query could I use ?

Comment: Are you asking for a query that will insert an entry for every date of the year?  I'm assuming English is your second language.  Your question sounds like you want to insert a date one year from now.

Comment: Ya, I mean every date of the year not a date one year from now.

Comment: I got this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`

Comment: Ok, I had to install MySQL real quick to get all the syntax right, but the updated answer should now work.

Comment: How could I create store procedure and call it on phpmyadmin ?

Comment: run each of those two queries.  I built and ran them in phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay, that's works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it first get all date between to date and add it.

```
insert into day (date)
    select * from 
    (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
    where selected_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: I got this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as 
    select * from 
    (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000' at line 1`

Comment: oh  remove **as**. check it now

Comment: Can you help me with this questions [Resul query with if condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929355/return-query-result-with-if-condition)

Comment: I can not understand your if condition. so first put table with all possible value 0 and 1. and show what is the imp of date

Comment: I just edited my questions, please look at that.

Answer (score -1):

In mysql you can choose the column to only be filled with a date format. You can insert the data as '2017' or '17'. It will work both fine.