# Return query result with if condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have some table structure like this.

table `property_day`

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 0        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 0        | 0
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

table `rooms`

```
room_id | name      | property_id
----------------------------
1       | Deluxe    | 5
2       | Superior  | 5
3       | Executive | 5
```

I want to show all that room with if condition inside query. I show that room with date check in and date check out.

In table `property_day` column **check_in** and **check_out** is used for indicate guest cannot check in on that date or cannot check out on that date or cannot check in and check out on that date. Value **0** indicate guest can check in or check out but value **1** is indicate guest cannot check in or check out.

This is the if condition :

1. If I check in on 2017-03-27 and check out on 2017-03-28 and value in column `check_in` and `check_out` is **0** on that date I want to show all room in `property_id` **5**.
2. If I check in on 2017-03-27 and check out on 2017-03-28 and value in column `check_in` on 2017-03-27 is **1**, I doesn't want to show all room.
3. If I check in on 2017-03-27 and check out on 2017-03-28 and value in column `check_out` on 2017-03-28 is **1** , I also doesn't want to show all room.
4. If I check in on 2017-03-27 and check out on 2017-03-29 and value in column `check_in` and `check_out` in 2017-03-28 is **1**, I want to show all room.
5. If I check in on 2017-03-27 and check out on 2017-03-29 and value in column `check_in` and `check_out` in 2017-03-28 is **0**, I also want to show all room.

This is table structure for condition number 1 :

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 0        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 0        | 0
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

This is table structure for condition number 2 :

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 1        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 0        | 0
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

This is table structure for condition number 3 :

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 0        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 0        | 1
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

This is table structure for condition number 4 :

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 0        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 1        | 1
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

This is table structure for condition number 5 :

```
propday_id | date       | property_id | check_in | check_out
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2017-03-26 | 5           | 0        | 0
2          | 2017-03-27 | 5           | 0        | 0
3          | 2017-03-28 | 5           | 0        | 0
4          | 2017-03-29 | 5           | 0        | 0
```

This is the query which I already try but doesn't give result what I want.

```
SELECT p.*, r.*
FROM property_day p
JOIN rooms r on p.property_id = r.property_id
WHERE p.property_id = 5 AND p.check_in = 0 OR p.check_out = 0
```

That's simple query because I doesn't know to make some query with that if condition.

Please anyone help me to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the desired output from the query.

Comment: I just want to show room name in table `rooms` with that condition. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `SELECT p.*, r.*
FROM property_day p
JOIN rooms r on p.property_id = r.property_id
WHERE p.check_in = 0 OR p.check_out = 0`

Comment: I don't see how the two tables are actually related.

Comment: I used this `property_day p JOIN rooms r on p.property_id = r.property_id` @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `SELECT r.name
FROM property_day p
JOIN rooms r on p.property_id = r.property_id
WHERE p.property_id = 5 AND p.check_in = 0 OR p.check_out = 0`

Comment: @EhsanIlahi Your queries are far from the OP's requirements.

Comment: `SELECT r.name as name FROM rooms r , property_day p where p.property_id = r.property_id and p.property_id = 5 AND p.check_in = 0 OR p.check_out = 0 `

@TimBiegeleisen is it ok ...?

Comment: Can you show the expected output you needed

Comment: what is different in table structure 1 and 5 ? so please explain about date also. or it is fix ?

Comment: condition 1 and 5 are mostly same but the different is in date check in and check out. @krishnpatel

Comment: yes but table structure are same for 1 and 5. so date are fix ?

Comment: ya, the table is same and the date are fix @krishnpatel

Answer (score 0):

Please use mysql CASE... THEN ... END statement to get the result

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

Comment: Can you give some example with my condition in questions ?

Comment: This is just an example

case when (check_in_date = '2017-03-27' && check_out_date = '2017-03-28' && check_in==1) then 'dont show' else 'show all' end case

Answer (score 0):

The `IF()` mysql syntax goes as this:

> [IF(expression , true, false);](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php)

You can create a statement like the example below. I haven't tested it but if it works, then good. You can re-rwite it though if you figured out a best way for your desired result. I didn't include the condition of `check_in` and `check_out` for value 1 and 0 because they are confusing and results to I don't know (in my pov of understanding your if conditions), but you can add them if you insist:

```
SELECT p.property_id, 
    IF(p.date = '2017-03-27' OR p.date = '2017-03-28',
        IF(p.property_id = 5, 
            r.name,
            '---'
        ), 
        IF(p.date = '2017-03-29', 
            r.name,
            '---'
        )
    ) AS your_result
FROM property_day p
JOIN rooms r on p.property_id = r.property_id
WHERE p.date >= '2017-03-27' AND p.date <= '2017-03-29'
```