# Count orders in price range, and group by week number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have to get some statistics from a MySQL Database, i need to get the amount of orders in ranges of order size, and then i need to group by WEEK, from the table created_at in orders

I hope this makes sense.

Here's what i have been able to come up with, but i have very little experience in advanced MySQL.

```
SELECT 
   x.Kurv, COALESCE(ordre, 0) AS ordre
FROM (
  SELECT "0 - 100" AS Kurv
  UNION SELECT "100 - 200"
  UNION SELECT "200 - 300"
  UNION SELECT "300 - 400"
  UNION SELECT "400 - 500"
  UNION SELECT "500 - 600"
  UNION SELECT "over 600" ) x
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
  CASE when base_total_ex_tax >= 0 and base_total_ex_tax <= 100 then "0 - 100"
       when base_total_ex_tax > 100 and base_total_ex_tax <= 200 then "100 - 200"
       when base_total_ex_tax > 200 and base_total_ex_tax <= 300 then "200 - 300"
       when base_total_ex_tax > 300 and base_total_ex_tax <= 400 then "300 - 400"
       when base_total_ex_tax > 400 and base_total_ex_tax <= 500 then "400 - 500"
       when base_total_ex_tax > 500 and base_total_ex_tax <= 600 then "500 - 600"
       else "over 600"
  END AS Kurv,
  COUNT(*) as ordre
FROM orders
WHERE
    created_at > '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
    && 
    status_id != 'canceled'
GROUP BY 1) 
    y ON x.Kurv = y.Kurv
```

Which outputs the ranges and orders fine, i just need to add the week group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the week with `CONCAT(YEAR(date), '/', WEEK(date))`.  Then you can just group on it:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(YEAR(date), '/', WEEK(date)) as wk
,       CASE
        WHEN amount <= 100 THEN '0 - 100'
        WHEN amount <= 200 THEN '100 - 200'
        ELSE '> 200'
        END as kurve
,       COUNT(*)
FROM    orderstable
GROUP BY
        wk
,       kurve
```

[Example at rextester.](http://rextester.com/RXVU69910)

If you want to list all kurves and weeks, even those without orders, you can add all kurves (as you've already done) and [all weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238/50552) to the right-hand side of a left join.  That's typically easier to do client side.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

Please check below query

```
      SELECT 
   Y.WEEK_VAL , x.Kurv, COALESCE(ordre, 0) AS ordre
FROM (
  SELECT "0 - 100" AS Kurv
  UNION SELECT "100 - 200"
  UNION SELECT "200 - 300"
  UNION SELECT "300 - 400"
  UNION SELECT "400 - 500"
  UNION SELECT "500 - 600"
  UNION SELECT "over 600" ) x
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT WEEK(created_at) WEEK_VAL, 
  CASE when 5 >= 0 and 5 <= 100 then "0 - 100"
       when 5 > 100 and 5 <= 200 then "100 - 200"
       when 5 > 200 and 5 <= 300 then "200 - 300"
       when 5 > 300 and 5 <= 400 then "300 - 400"
       when 5 > 400 and 5 <= 500 then "400 - 500"
       when 5 > 500 and 5 <= 600 then "500 - 600"
       else "over 600"
  END AS Kurv,
  COUNT(*) as ordre
FROM orders GROUP BY WEEK(created_at) ,  CASE when 5 >= 0 and 5 <= 100 then "0 - 100"
       when 5 > 100 and 5 <= 200 then "100 - 200"
       when 5 > 200 and 5 <= 300 then "200 - 300"
       when 5 > 300 and 5 <= 400 then "300 - 400"
       when 5 > 400 and 5 <= 500 then "400 - 500"
       when 5 > 500 and 5 <= 600 then "500 - 600"
       else "over 600"
  END) 
    y ON x.Kurv = y.Kurv
```

Comment: I think belive you did, but i get an error:

SQL-Error (1054) unknown column 'Y.WEEK_VAL' in field list.

Thank you for the very fast reply! :-)

Comment: Are you able to run just inner query "Y"? Please confirm.

Comment: I cant get that working either, but it might be me, not being experinced enough. :-O

Comment: Thank your for your time, i found a solution from anouther response. :-)