# adding rows with 0 values

Tags: mysql, select, join, insert

I have a result set like:

```
fullDate            service          Monthlybilled
-----------------------------------------------------
2015-08-01          wash car         300.00
2015-10-01          brake test       500.00
2015-12-01          oil change       200.00
```

I need to show another one like:

```
fullDate            service          Monthlybilled
-----------------------------------------------------
....

2015-07-01          none             0.00
2015-08-01          wash car         300.00
2015-09-01          none             0.00
2015-10-01          brake test       500.00
2015-11-01          none             0.00
2015-12-01          oil change       200.00       
2016-01-01          none             0.00
...
```

i.e.  for those months where no activity was "detected" I need to add a row
that says   none   and  0.00

Any suggestions, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this:

1. Write a query that generated all the dates between the range (as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)) and perform a `LEFT JOIN` with it to get all the dates with zero entries.
2. Create a calendar table which maintains all the dates and `LEFT JOIN` it with current query to get all the records.
3. Write the logic in your application/service layer to fill the missing dates with 0 values.

I would recommend option 3.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table containing all the month values you need.

Then use LEFT OUTER JOIN to the table with your service dates.

```
SELECT
  alldates.fullDate,
  COALESCE(service.service, 'none') AS service,
  COALESCE(service.MonthlyBilled, 0.00) AS MonthlyBilled
FROM alldates
LEFT OUTER JOIN service
  ON alldates.fullDate = service.fullDate
```