# MySQL count day of week between two dates over a table

Tags: mysql, count, dayofweek

I have a booking table with the following columns:

id, start_date, end_date

I want to know which days have had the most bookings over my dataset.

I can use dayofweek() on the start date and group by this also and use a count(*). But I also want to include the days between the start of booking and end.

An example output wouldbe

```
dayofweek     count(*)
1             1
2             1
3             1
4             2
5             3
6             3
7             1
```

for the following set

```
id       start_date          end_date
1        2017-10-01          2017-10-07
2        2017-10-04          2017-10-07
3        2017-10-06          2017-10-08
```

Comment: Use a calendar table (with all dates you need) and join it to your table using a BETWEEN condition.

Comment: It's unfortunate that October began on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to know something like how many rooms are filled for each date for the duration between the start and end. The"trick" here is that a long period between start/end will repeat the day or week and/or that the end day of week might be smaller than the start day of week. So, I have:

1. generated a list of 100,000 dates (1 per row)
2. joined those dates between the start/end of your table
3. converted each joined rows to a day of week number to be counted
4. left joined to a list of 1 to 7, and counted the rows of step 3

NOTE: if the end_date is a "check out date" then it may be necessary to deduct 1 day from each record to compensate (which is not done below).

This approach is available for review here at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52fb7/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `start_date` datetime, `end_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `start_date`, `end_date`)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-09-21 00:00:00', '2017-10-07 00:00:00'), ## added this row
    (1, '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-07 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2017-10-04 00:00:00', '2017-10-07 00:00:00'),
    (3, '2017-10-06 00:00:00', '2017-10-08 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query**:

```
set @commence := str_to_date('2000-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')

select
    w.dy
  , count(t.wdy)
from (
      select 1 dy union all select 2 dy union all select 3 dy union all
      select 4 dy union all select 5 dy union all select 6 dy union all select 7 dy
      ) w
left join (
      select DAYOFWEEK(cal.dy) wdy
      from (
              select adddate( @commence ,t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) dy 
              from  (     select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t0 
              cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1 
              cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2 
              cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3 
              cross join (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4
          ) cal
      INNER JOIN Table1 t on cal.dy between t.start_date and t.end_date
      ) t on w.dy = t.wdy
group by
    w.dy
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52fb7/1/1)**:

```
| dy | count(t.wdy) |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |            4 |
|  2 |            3 |
|  3 |            3 |
|  4 |            4 |
|  5 |            5 |
|  6 |            6 |
|  7 |            6 |
```

Also see: [How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query) where the accepted answer is the basis for the set of cross joins that produces 100,000 dates starting from a nominated date. I modified that however for syntax (explicit cross join syntax), a parameter as start point, and use of `union all` for efficiency.

Comment: This works! However I have a test table with 100 rows and it currently takes 20 seconds, how well would this query run if say I had 100,000?

Comment: a. I cannot really predict that, and b. it most probably depend on your indexes, and c. instead of a dynamically generated list of dates you could create a table instead and index that also. Always refer to explain plans for performance details. If asking a new question about performance include full DDL of tables and related indexes. PLUS the explain plan output (as text)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a recursive table:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date, end_date, DAYOFWEEK(start_date) AS dw from bookings
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date INTERVAL 1 DAY), end_date, DAYOFWEEK(date)
    FROM cte WHERE date <= end_date
)
SELECT COUNT(*), dw FROM cte GROUP BY dw
```

Comment: Additional Note:  Recursive tables might not be available, depending on the version used (i.e. it's not possible with MariaDB < 10.2)

Comment: Using MySQL 5.7