# PostgreSQL get aggregated results based on two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,
 
1. `items` 
2. `festival_rents`

Sample records:
`items`

```
id | name   |  rent 
------------------------
1  |  Car   |   100             
2  |  Truck |   150   
3  |  Van   |   200
```

Sample records:
`festival_rents`

```
id | items_id   | start_date | end_date   | rent 
------------------------------------------------
1  |  1         | 2018-07-01 | 2018-07-02 | 200  
2  |  1         | 2018-07-04 | 2018-07-06 | 300
3  |  3         | 2018-07-06 | 2018-07-07 | 400
```

The table `items` contains list of items with `name` and `rent`. Each item in the `items` table may or may not have `festival_rents`. The table `festival_rents` has higher rents for each item for a date range with `start_date` and `end_date`. It is possible for a item to have multiple `festival_rents` with different date ranges. But it's for sure that date ranges for multiple `festival_rents` belonging to a same `item` won't collide and all date ranges are isolated.

The query that I'm looking for is, for a given `start_date` and `end_date` range, for each item in the `items` table, calculate the total rent and display each item with it's calculated total rent. The rent calculation for each item should include the `festival_rents` also, if any of the `items` has `festival_rents` falling within the given `start_date` and `end_date`.

Expected result:

Input: `start_date=2018-07-01` and `end_date=2018-07-06`

Output:

```
id | name   | total_price 
------------------------
1  |  Car   |   1100          // 1st 2 days festival rent + 1 day normal rent + last 3 days festival rent (2 * 200) + (1 * 100) + (3 * 200)  
2  |  Truck |   900           // 6 days normal rent (6 * 150)
3  |  Van   |   1400          // 5 days normal rent + 1 day festival rent (200 * 5) + (400 * 1)
```

Comment: mysql or postgresql? choose one.

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of days either on a table or create on the fly:

[How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)

[Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql)

```
SELECT i.name, SUM (f.rent)
FROM allDays a
JOIN festival_rents f
  ON a.day >= f.start_date 
 AND a.day < f.end_date  
JOIN items i
  ON f.item_id = i.item_id 
WHERE a.day BETWEEN @start_date
                AND @end_date
GROUP BY i.name
```

I assume the end_date is open range. So if you have ranges `[A,B)` and `[B,C)` Date B will have the rent from `[B,C)`

Comment: Is it possible to do the aggregation without creating a table on the fly?. I don't understand what you meant by `end_date` is open range in the last line of your answer. If you are talking about the `end_date` in `festival_rents`, then end_dates won't collide with other `festival_rents` ranges. So with the example you gave, it will be `[A, A]` and `[B, C]`

Comment: open range mean: `start <= value < end` .... close range mean:  `start <= value <= end`. And isn't possible because you need to assign a property to each day. You can create a permanent table to keep all days. That is only `365` rows for each years. or `36.500` for 100 years So isn't a big deal.