# how I query mysql given date range and joined two tables?

Tags: mysql, database, orm, doctrine

[image]

Assume I have two tables, one room and rented. How can I get mysql join result like the table below.

[image]

display the availability for each room_id given quantity from the first column and booked status on second table for each date given date range.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure `from` and `until` are MySQL `DATE` types, and not stored as strings.

If those columns are MySQL `DATE` datatype, then we can do something like this:

```
 SELECT r.id AS room_id 
      , r.quantity - IFNULL(SUM(IF('2012-12-01' BETWEEN v.from AND v.until, v.quantity, 0)),0) AS `1`
      , r.quantity - IFNULL(SUM(IF('2012-12-02' BETWEEN v.from AND v.until, v.quantity, 0)),0) AS `2`
      , r.quantity - IFNULL(SUM(IF('2012-12-03' BETWEEN v.from AND v.until, v.quantity, 0)),0) AS `3`
      , ... 

   FROM room r
   LEFT
   JOIN room_reservation v
     ON v.room_id  = r.id
    AND v.until   >= '2012-12-01'
    AND v.from    <= '2012-12-31'
  GROUP BY r.id, r.quantity
  ORDER BY r.id
```

If those aren't `DATE` datatypes, and aren't strings in canonical `YYYY-MM-DD` format, then we can use the MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert to `DATE`. The SQL will just be a little messier.

Comment: i did figure out query like this, i thought, there will be a query to generate date column given date range without generate it dynamically. in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238 the query generated date. I wonder, if mysql able to make some kind of pivot table

Comment: There wasn't any indication in the question that you already had a query like this. It is helpful, when asking a question, to show what you have tried. The number of columns to be returned, the datatype and the name of each column must be specified in the SQL; this can't be dynamic within the context of a single SELECT statement. Certainly, there are other patterns that will return an equivalent result. It would be simpler to return the results on separate rows, row-wise rather than column wise. But if we need to the result returned as 31 columns, thenconditional aggregation is the way to go.