# MySQL: list of dates between a range with joined subselect

Tags: mysql

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238/160044) that I can easily select a list of dates in MySQL.

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

So far so good: now, for each `selected_date`, I'd like ie. to count the records in another table (say `reports`) where field `reports_date` matches `selected_date`, thus obtaining a recordset like this:

```
| selected_date | reports_count |
|---------------|---------------|
| 2012-02-10    | 12            |
| 2012-02-11    | 10            |
| 2012-02-12    | 3             |
| 2012-02-13    | 0             |
| 2012-02-14    | 9             |
| 2012-02-15    | 15            |
```

I tried to add the subquery `select count(*) as reports_count from reports where reports_dated = selected_date` somewhere, but with no luck

Please, any help?
Thanks

Comment: As has presumably been mentioned before, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.selected_date, COUNT(t2.reports_dated) AS reports_count
FROM (
select * 
from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
) s
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON s.selected_date = t2.reports_dated
GROUP BY s.selected_date
ORDER BY selected_date;
```