# Displaying all the dates between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table of the form:

```
date       hrs
01-01-2020  5
03-01-2020  1
05-01-2020  2
```

I want to get all the dates from 01-01-2020 to 05-01-2020 as output when I use the mysql command in php:

```
date       hrs
01-01-2020  5
02-01-2020  0
03-01-2020  1
04-01-2020  0
05-01-2020  2
```

I have used the following statement:

```
SELECT dates FROM booking WHERE date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'"
```

where start date is 01-01-2020 and end date is 05-01-2020. But I got the first table format not the second one.

Comment: Did you use group by date in Query?

Comment: Given that you have access to application code, just handle this logic there. Note that dates in sql adhere to a specific format, so fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could prepare all the dates between the two specified dates. Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238/9321816), the subquery would be:

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '$start' AND '$end'
```

Then I would left join this table to the table you have, as follows:

```
select v.selected_date , coalesce(booking.hrs, 0) from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
left join booking on v.selected_date = booking.date
where v.selected_date between '$start' AND '$end'
```

I'm not sure if there's a simpler answer, but this worked for me.

The [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296238/9321816) has explanations to how the subquery can obtain all dates between two given dates. Hope this helps!

Comment: Generate 100000 dates for to select only 5 from them? Monsieur knows a lot about perversions...

Comment: OP just provided a format, I was trying to be conservative and stick to a well-accepted answer in existence :)

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL server version is 8+ use

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS ( SELECT MIN(dates) dates
         FROM booking 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dates + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE dates < ( SELECT MAX(dates)
                         FROM booking ) )
SELECT dates, hrs
FROM booking
UNION ALL
SELECT dates, 0
FROM cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM booking
                   WHERE booking.dates = cte.dates )
ORDER BY dates
```

Answer (score 0):

most easily you can use like this :

```
SET @date_min = '2020-01-01';
SET @date_max = '2020-01-05';

SELECT
   date_generator.date as dates,
   IFNULL(hrs, 0) as hrs
from (
   select DATE_ADD(@date_min, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where DATE_ADD(@date_min,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @date_min AND @date_max
) date_generator
left join booking on DATE(`date`) = date_generator.date
GROUP BY `date`;
```

so here I am creating a temporary table date_generator will dates in between of given date range and join to with your main table (transactions).

output as expected:

```
dates      | hrs 
01-01-2020 | 5
02-01-2020 | 0
03-01-2020 | 1
04-01-2020 | 0
05-01-2020 | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM booking 
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND date <= '2020-05-01 00:00:00'
```