# Convert Records in a mysql query to show for every month between a start and end date

Tags: mysql, date, subquery, grouping

Hi I have a table/query in Mysql like this :

```
ActivityId | ActivityName | Start     | End        | 
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 |
```

I want to generate months and repeat other data between a start and end date.
Like This

```
ActivityId | ActivityName | Start     | End        | Month   |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 06-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 07-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 08-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 09-2010 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 09-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 10-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 11-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 12-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 01-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 02-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 03-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 04-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 05-2013 |
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Does It matter ? Mysql version 5.7.11 . I was thinking of some query solution.

Comment: It's a much easier problem to solve in MySQL 8+. Anyway, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it how can I solve this problem with the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query (based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)) to generate all the months between the start and end month, along with the corresponding values from your `activity` table:

```
SELECT ActivityId, ActivityName, Start, End, 
       DATE_FORMAT(Start + INTERVAL t1.i*10 + t0.i MONTH, '%m-%Y') AS Month
FROM
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0
CROSS JOIN
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1
JOIN activity ON DATE_FORMAT(Start + INTERVAL t1.i*10 + t0.i MONTH, '%Y-%m') <= DATE_FORMAT(End, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY ActivityId, DATE_FORMAT(Start + INTERVAL t1.i*10 + t0.i MONTH, '%Y-%m')
```

Output:

```
ActivityId | ActivityName | Start     | End        | Month   |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 06-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 07-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 08-2010 |
1          | A            |05-06-2010 | 10-09-2010 | 09-2010 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 09-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 10-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 11-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 12-2012 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 01-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 02-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 03-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 04-2013 |
2          | B            |01-09-2012 | 10-05-2013 | 05-2013 |
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6fb5a/4)

Comment: can you help me set collation for my newly added Month column. Its creating problem when saving as view.

Comment: @Sitepose what problem are you seeing? Can you make a demo out of my fiddle?

Comment: Actually when I save this query as a view, It sets the month column collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci while my other columns have utf8_unicode_ci. And when I further compare this column with other columns a new error comes : 

#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @Sitepose I can't reproduce... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bU7zphQoMnKog8MmgagbFm/0

Comment: You could try `CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(Start + INTERVAL t1.i*10 + t0.i MONTH, '%m-%Y') USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS Month`

Comment: I tried by adding this in above query, But it shows syntax error : Unrecognised keyword

Comment: @Sitepose working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2d4fa276d8260c26dbf6de4680d2dcd0

Comment: Yes It is working . Thanks .
Syntax error earlier because I was mistakenly only executing query without creating view.