# List dates from specific mysql table and return 0 if day does not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum, recursive-query

I'm trying to generate a result from a query that list the last 7 days from today (2020/07/15) and the views matching a specific code.
If in that day the code has no views, I want the day to return 0.

**Table Format**

```
    DAY    | CODE | VIEWS
2020-07-10 | 123  | 5
2020-07-11 | 123  | 2
2020-07-12 | 123  | 3
2020-07-15 | 123  | 8
2020-07-15 | 124  | 2
2020-07-15 | 125  | 2
```

**Expected result from code 123**

```
    DAY    | VIEWS
2020-07-09 | 0
2020-07-10 | 5
2020-07-11 | 2
2020-07-12 | 3
2020-07-13 | 0
2020-07-14 | 0
2020-07-15 | 8
```

I already found a way to generate the calendar dates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query) and adjust to my needs, but I don't know how to join the result with my table.

```
select * from 
  (select 
    adddate(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, t0) day 
    from   
      (select 1 t0 
       union select 1 
       union select 2 
       union select 3 
       union select 4 
       union select 5 
       union select 6 
       union select 7) t0) v
```

Any help would by apreceated.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a recursive query - available in MySQL 8.0:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select current_date - interval 6 day dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cte where dt < current_date
)
select c.dt, coalesce(sum(t.views), 0) views
from cte
left join mytable t on t.day = c.dt
group by c.dt
order by c.dt
```

You can also manually build a derived table, as you originaly intended to (this would work on all versions of MySQL):

```
select current_date - interval d.n day dt, coalesce(sum(t.views), 0) views
from (
    select 0 n 
    union all select 1 
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
) d
left join mytable t on t.day = current_date - interval d.n day
group by d.n
order by d.n desc
```

Comment: Hi, using your second suggestion, when I add the where clause to filter the code (where code = 123) it only returns the dates that match the code. Anyway to adjust this? Thanks

Comment: @nfn: move the filter to the `on` clause of the `join`: `left join mytable t on t.day = current_date - interval d.n day and t.code = 123`