# Get dates lies between two date ranges, as per the Day of week in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fromDate, toDate and dayOfWeek in mysql. I want all the dates that lies on the particular dayofWeek and lies between fromDate and toDate.
eg

```
fromDate- '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
toDate- '2021-09-30 00:00:00'
dayOfWeek(4,5) i.e thurday and Friday
```

output

| output |
| --- |
| 2021-09-02 |
| 2021-09-03 |
| 2021-09-01 |
| 2021-09-10 |
| 2021-09-16 |
| 2021-09-17 |
| 2021-09-23 |
| 2021-09-24 |
| 2021-09-30 |

I am using MYSQLWORKBENCH 8.0

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output in text format. Also show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: And specify **precise** MySQL version - it is critical for your task.

Comment: Do you have fromDate, toDate and dayOfWeek in one table or those are 3 different tables?

Comment: @Lidbey they are in different table...we need to use join ..query would be something like SELECT DISTINCT
    slot.tl_id, dow, tl.start_datetime, tl.end_datetime
FROM
    t_slots AS slot,
    listing AS tl
WHERE
    t_date = '0000-00-00'
        AND tl.tl_id = slot.tl_id

Comment: @Akina using  MYSQLWORKBENCH 8.0

Comment: @astentx, i have updated the question, please check I have provided the sample data. We can ignore the time as well

Comment: Slot, listing? Please include them in your request. At first it seemed you want to generate a result set of dates from the parameters, but now I suppose you rather want to select all rows from a table the dates of which match the parameters (which are in the other table)? Please explain your tables, what columns there are and what the tables represent.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is only the tool you are using, by the way. It is not the DBMS. MySQL Workbench 8 supports all MySQL versions from 5.6 to 8.0. You see the MySQL version in the program's menu (Server / Server Status) or with SQL: `select @@version;` or `select version()`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In table we have many fields but I want tl_id and dates(which is lying in fromdate- toDate criteria)

Comment: *I have provided the sample data.* Sample data must be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO textual formatted code. And it must be accompanied by desired output for shown sample data.

Comment: But how are the tables related? Again: Please edit your request. Show us the tables involved. Show some sample data and expected result. We don't know your tables. You won't get any answers until we know what you are actually asking. I wouldn't insist on create table and insert statements, as long as I see what the tables contain and to what result that leads. But all you have shown us are parameters and dates. How are they connected to the tables you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

here for you

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30' 
having WEEKDAY(selected_date) in (3,4)
ORDER BY selected_date ASC;
```

0 is monday , 3 is thurday ...
from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get all Thursday and Friday between two dates. I use `LAST_DAY()` function (last month day) to set the end of the interval, but you can hard code a specific date:

```
WITH RECURSIVE days AS (SELECT '2021-09-01' as day

                        UNION ALL 
              
                        SELECT DATE_ADD(day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                        FROM days
                        WHERE day < LAST_DAY(day))
              
SELECT *
FROM days
WHERE weekday(day) IN (3,4);
```

Output:

| day |
| --- |
| 2021-09-02 |
| 2021-09-03 |
| 2021-09-09 |
| 2021-09-10 |
| 2021-09-16 |
| 2021-09-17 |
| 2021-09-23 |
| 2021-09-24 |
| 2021-09-30 |