# How to retrieve each minute per row b/w two timestamps in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I would require your kind assistance in a query to fetch each minute per row b/w two dates in MySQL.
(this is part of a larger analysis that requires per-minute aggregation of stats. Group  by would only work when that minute is available in the timestamps but I want all of the in b/w minutes as well)

e.g:
Given: start_date: 2022-10-01 20:00:00, end_date: 2022-10-01 21:00:00

**Output:**

```
.............................
date_min_col
.............................
2022-10-01 20:01:00
2022-10-01 20:02:00
2022-10-01 20:03:00
2022-10-01 20:04:00
2022-10-01 20:05:00
.
.
.
2022-10-01 21:00:00
```

Comment: Have you tried adapting the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query helps you:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE MinuteList AS (
  SELECT '2022-10-01 20:00:00' AS minute_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT minute_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
  FROM MinuteList
  WHERE minute_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE <= '2022-10-01 21:00:00'
)
SELECT minute_date
FROM MinuteList;
```

It will return something like this:

[image]

***UPDATE 1***

In case you don't have access to the RECURSIVE CTE, I assume you can have a table that stores the number sequence for you.

once you generate the table and fill it you can use it for generating your dates.

```sql
create table seq_numbers(
  seq int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- fill the table with the sequence of numbers and the maximum number in the table can be your max diff between dates you have, otherwise, the result is less than you expect.
INSERT INTO seq_numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),....,(3600);
```

With this command you will be able to generate your desired output

```sql
SELECT '2022-10-01 20:01:00' + INTERVAL seq MINUTE
FROM seq_numbers
where seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2022-10-01 20:01:00', '2022-10-01 21:05:00')
```

[image]

Comment: I got this solution from another source as well, but Recursive cte is not supported in my environment.

Comment: @kestrel Do you have access to make the procedure?

Comment: @kestrel There is also a trick you can use. You need to add a new Table and prefill it with the maximum difference you think you will have. for example, you say I always don't have more than `3600` minutes between `start` and `end`. See the Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

If CTE is not supported then

```
SELECT @startdate + INTERVAL n1.n * 10 + n2.n + 1 MINUTE timepoint
FROM ( SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... SELECT 5) n1
JOIN ( SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... SELECT 9) n2
HAVING timepoint <= @enddate
```

The amount of synthetic tables and their sizes must allow to generate the numbers not less than the timerange width.

Also you may use service numbers table created in service database.