# SQL - Show months without data using group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been searching without success for a way to list the data of all months, on format `YEAR-MONTH`, between two dates in a report.

I have this query that work well but doesn't show the months when doesn't exist data.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(bt.date_submitted),'%Y-%m') AS month, count(*) as the_count
        FROM bug_table bt
        WHERE bt.category_id=2 
        AND  bt.date_submitted BETWEEN " . db_prepare_string( $db_datetimes['start'] ) . "
        AND " . db_prepare_string( $db_datetimes['finish'] ) . "
        GROUP BY month
        ORDER BY month ASC
```

The `date_submitted` is a UNIX_TIMESTAMP and `$db_datetimes` is a associative array on php that store the dates chosen by the user.

For instance, I want a list all months between 2016-10-01 and 2017-03-20. I got :

```
 month   | the_count
 2017-03       7
 2017-02       5
 2017-01       2
 2016-12      10
```

But I would like as below, including zero on months that have any record:

```
 month   | the_count
 2017-03       7
 2017-02       5
 2017-01       2
 2016-12      10
 2016-11       0
 2016-10       0
```

Sincerely I prefer to solve this problem on SQL, but any ideas using SQL or php will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with all months and do a left join from that table to your main table. And then replace NULLs with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to join them on the dates
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN date ON table1.date=table2.date

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with one of the following approaches:

- Create a list of `month-year` values dynamically (using a query) and `LEFT JOIN` result of that query to the one you are using. An example SO answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511409/creating-a-list-of-month-names-between-two-dates-in-mysql).
- Create a `calenar` table and populate it with `dates`. You can then use the same `LEFT JOIN` with `calendar` and get the values.
- Handle this logic in service/business layer of your application (i.e.create an array of month-year and show the values on User Interface based on results retrieved from `db`).

I would recommend using third approach as it's the cleanest one and won't add complexity to your db or service layer.