# List of months within multiple date ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I have a list of date ranges and I like to get a list of all months that are within these date ranges. I can query my date ranges like so:

```
Select id, start, end 
From date_range
```

And this query would give the following output:

```
1, 01-01-2016, 25-03-2016
2, 26-03-2016, 30-03-2016
3, 30-12-2016, 08-01-2017
```

Now I would like to find a MySQL query that just lists all months within these date ranges. So it should give the following output:

```
01-2016
02-2016
03-2016
12-2016
01-2017
```

There are already examples here on how to get a list of month between two dates, such as:

- [Creating a list of month names between two dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511409/creating-a-list-of-month-names-between-two-dates-in-mysql)
- [How to get a list of months between two dates in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811568/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

But these examples are about a single date range, but I have multiple date ranges. It would be great if someone can find an sql query for my problem.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you want all months within the date ranges, or simply the month/year of each start/end date in the ranges?

Comment: @Sloan: I want all months within the date ranges. So if one date range spans over 5 months, then all 5 months should appear.

Comment: This is really a display issue and, as such, best resolved in application code

Comment: you can just use `distinct(month(date))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
#DROP TABLE IF EXISTS monthTest;
CREATE TABLE monthTest(id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `start` DATETIME, `end`DATETIME);

INSERT INTO monthTest(`start`, `end`) VALUES
    ('2016-01-01', '2016-03-25'),
    ('2016-03-26', '2016-03-30'),
    ('2016-12-30', '2017-08-01');

SELECT A.`start`, A.`end`, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(A.`start`, INTERVAL B.help_keyword_id MONTH), '%Y%m') FROM
    monthTest A,
    mysql.help_keyword B
WHERE PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(A.`end`, '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(A.`start`, '%Y%m')) >= B.help_keyword_id
ORDER BY A.id;
```

Note that this query in the second `JOIN` table has a dependency that this table must contain more rows than the maximum number of months between any two dates and the join field must be an incrementing `INTEGER` starting from 0. This is due to the limitation that mysql doesn't (yet) contain a row generator so a workaround is necessary.

Regards,

James