# Get values for every day in specific month (or between months)

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

This is my sql:

```
select * from table as t 
where DateAndTime BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2012-01-25'
```

Question:
* For example, i need get data from January, 2012 for every day (except weekends).

How can i do it?

Comment: that is, you want to `GROUP BY` the day part of the DateAndTime field, ignoring the weekends?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    yourtable AS T 
WHERE 
    yourdatetimefield BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
                              STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
AND 
    DAYOFWEEK(yourdatetimefield) <> 1 AND    '  Sunday
    DAYOFWEEK(yourdatetimefield) <> 7        '  Saturday 
GROUP BY
    DAY(yourdatetimefield);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT * 
from table as t 
where (DateAndTime BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2012-01-25') AND
       DateAndTime NOT IN ('2011-03-03', '2011-03-10') -- Put the excempted
                                                       -- dates here
```

Comment: does BETWEEN work with strings?

Comment: you can use `DATE` function. FOr example, `DATE('2011-03-03')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table as t 
where DateAndTime BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2012-01-25' 
AND (DATEPART(weekday, DateAndTime ) <> 1 and  DATEPART(weekday,DateAndTime ) <> 6)
```

`(DATEPART(weekday, DateAndTime ) = 1`  is sunday
`(DATEPART(weekday, DateAndTime ) = 6`  is saturday

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE DateAndTime BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2012-01-25'
AND WEEKDAY(DateAndTime) <= 4
```