# Generate Month Row and Left Join With Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these data in my database

```
+--------------+------------+
| TRX_DATE     |  AMOUNT    |
+--------------+------------+
| 2012-12-01   |  100.00    |
| 2012-12-07   |  125.00    |
+--------------+------------+
```

I need these data Left Join with **"Generate full Month Row"** like this

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+
|   DATE       |  TRX_DATE  |   AMOUNT    |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
| 2012-12-01   | 2012-12-01 |   100.00    |
| 2012-12-02   |    NULL    |    NULL     |
....
| 2012-12-07   | 2012-12-07 |   125.00    |
....
+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

How to do that thank you.

Edit : More Clarify Question

Comment: As in loop through all the days of the month and join with that?

Comment: insert all the dates of month in a temp table and left join temp table

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is dates between two dates of month and then you can do left join with it.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME   
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = '2012-12-01'
SET @endDate = '2011-12-31';

WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)

SELECT Date
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN yourtablename ON yourtablename.trx_date=dates.date
```

[see the SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) :- the link will show you some good techniques to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
LEFT JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.trx_date = table_name2.trx_date

You need to join on unique data from both tables.

Comment: COLUMN "DATE" is not real table I try to generate full month row and left join with my data

Sorry for unclear question.