# only allowing available dates to be selected in a drop down menu? php mysql html

Tags: php, html, mysql

On my form that users fill in and their data is sent to mysl database, there is a drop down menu which includes dates. what i need to do is make the drop down menu so that it only includes dates that are available. so i can query the database to find a certain date and if there is already an event for that date, then i can somehow take that date out from the drop down menu? i can imagine this being lengthy and complicated and wondered if anyone had ideas of how to do this effectively? there are a lot of dates, like two months worth, i dont really want to have to make a query for each date but im not entirely sure what else i could do. thanks for any replies.

i havent TRIED anything yet, have only had ideas. i was just wondering if anyone had any better ideas which werent getting every available date FROM mysql but instead just query dates from mysql that arent available then take that date away from the drop down? 
cutting out the rest of the input of the form -
html:

```
<div class="title"><h1>Booking Private Hire</h1></div>
</head>
<body>
<form name="second" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" method="POST"     action="thirdform.php">
<table summary="Second form">

<tr>
<td><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
<td><select name="date" size="1">
<option value="01-03-13">01-03-13</option>
<option value="02-03-13">02-03-13</option>
<option value="03-03-13">03-03-13</option>
<option value="04-03-13">04-03-13</option>
<option value="05-03-13">05-03-13</option>
<option value="06-03-13">06-03-13</option>
<option value="07-03-13">07-03-13</option>
<option value="08-03-13">08-03-13</option>
<option value="09-03-13">09-03-13</option>
<option value="10-03-13">10-03-13</option>
<option value="11-03-13">11-03-13</option>
<option value="12-03-13">12-03-13</option>
<option value="13-03-13">13-03-13</option>
<option value="14-03-13">14-03-13</option>
<option value="15-03-13">15-03-13</option>
<option value="16-03-13">16-03-13</option>
<option value="17-03-13">17-03-13</option>
<option value="18-03-13">18-03-13</option>
<option value="19-03-13">19-03-13</option>
<option value="20-03-13">20-03-13</option>
<option value="21-03-13">21-03-13</option>
<option value="22-03-13">22-03-13</option>
<option value="23-03-13">23-03-13</option>
<option value="24-03-13">24-03-13</option>
<option value="25-03-13">25-03-13</option>
<option value="26-03-13">26-03-13</option>
<option value="27-03-13">27-03-13</option>
<option value="28-03-13">28-03-13</option>
<option value="29-03-13">29-03-13</option>
<option value="30-03-13">30-03-13</option>
<option value="31-03-13">31-03-13</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="Continue" value="Continue" type="submit" ></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr> 

</table>
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

at the moment i have a hire table which looks like:

hireid  int(5)
customerid  int(5)
driverid    int(5)
time    time
endtime time
date    varchar(8)
length  int(11)
pickuplocation  varchar(25)
destination varchar(25)
useofbus    varchar(20)
numberofpeople  int(16)
cost    decimal(10,2)
day int(2)
month   int(2)
year    int(2)
payment varchar(6)
information varchar(6)

Comment: How about you post some code?

Comment: As njk says, please post some code/schema/dropdown example contents, what have you tried so far? However, as a suggestion, instead of removing dates, why not populate your dropdown using PHP, from the results of a SQL Query which pulls only the available dates.

Comment: well i could i guess, i was just wondering if there was a way to do it without doing that. hang on ill post some

Comment: I think the query will come down to whether your db lists all dates booked AND not booked, OR you only list those booked.  We need to see the schema I think.

Comment: which column specifies event? Can there be more than one event for a given date?

Comment: date varchar(8) - agree with SparKot, probably cause of the downvote you got too.  Id print this off and read it over a coffee http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html EDIT, maybe this is not the date that the booking is on, maybe its a person the person is meeting for a night out, or a type of Phoenix dactylifera (date palm) ...

Comment: well the whole thing is the event, a user decides what date and time they want to hire a bus and the hire table includes all the information linked to it. i would like it so that there is only one hire for each date.

Comment: i changed my date from date to varchar a while ago because it wasn't working with some other code i was doing, i also dont particularly like the format yyyy-mm-dd, i can't remember why i did change it though. is it a massive issue?

Comment: well queries don't like dates in string format!

Comment: hmmm. i think i changed it because the date wasnt being entered correctly when selected from the drop down into my database, but i can change that back and see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a temporary reference table to compare and query missing dates for booking.

[Stored procedure to accomplish it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an SQL Query that selects only the dates that have no event linked to it.
I do not know, how your er-scheme looks, so I can not tell you how this query should look like.
But you might want to look into the sql statement [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).