# Calendar with crosstab in jasperreports

Tags: calendar, jasper-reports, crosstab

I want to create a crosstab in the form of a calendar (Years as first group and months as second group in the columns) with jasperreports. I'm using MySQL database.

1) The first problem is, I'm getting only the months where the measure exists, I want to display all months of the year wether the measure exists for this month or not.

2) Second, I want to have a seperate crosstab for every year in a seperate page.

3) I can't get the months in the right order, they're ordered in alphabetical order.

4) I'm getting a blank first page before the crosstab displays I wanna get rid of. (I'm putting my crosstab in the summary band).

I know these are too much to ask, but I really looked them up deseperatly without any result :'(

Answer (score 0):

For most of this you can fix this in your sql.

1) see   [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

3) add a column to your sql and order by it.   example `SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03');`  will return "2"

For #2  you can create a group in Jasper of year (you can create this as a sql column as well or use the java date functions)  set the **start on new page** option for the group.  then move your crosstab into the detail band.

i think #2 will fix the #4 problem as well.

Comment: for 1) I'm already getting the dates, I just need to display ALL months

Comment: for 2) my crosstab won't move into the detail band