# Creating holidays calendar in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to export a calendar as PDF from a TimeOff module. See attached screenshot of the UI.

I did look around, and found one post that suggested using a Crosstab.
[Calendar with crosstab in jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767196/calendar-with-crosstab-in-jasperreports)

I tried this, but while this will work for an empty calendar, this does not quite work if I need to show holiday entries within those cells, especially holidays that span more than one cell.

Can anyone provide any pointers, even a starting point? I have considered hardcoding Frames or boxes, and then filling them with holiday entries, maybe a list for the day. But this still makes multi-day entries tricky to display.

[image: Calendar in the UI]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone:
This is what I am going ahead with for now.

One Frame per day, 35 Frames total in the Summary band to allow for 7 days in a week and max 5 weeks in a month. Each frame has a list filtered for Week m, day n - Sunday to Saturday.

I am manipulating the JSON data being sent to me in the Java service itself so that the template doesn't have to do much. The JSON data will have Calendar entry objects with day of the week, and week # in the month, plus other holiday info

Multi day entries are still an issue, but the user is going to have to live with it. I am going to sort each list by name of the person on the holiday entry - that should line up the entries in each cell in at least some of the cases, unless it is a multi-person calendar.