# return list of dates based on 2 dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I hope someone has a quick answer for this...

I have a start date and an end date.  What's the quickest/easiest way to produce a complete list of all included days?

```
startDate         endDate
------------------------------
2013-01-01        2013-01-07
```

would produce:

```
day        date
--------------------
 1        2013-01-01
 2        2013-01-02
 3        2013-01-03
 4        2013-01-04
 5        2013-01-05
 6        2013-01-06
 7        2013-01-07
```

Thank you for your kind attention! :)

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: @AaronBertrand The answers to the protected post includes solutions for MSSQL as well, see the 2nd answer for example.

Comment: @jpw the question is tagged MySQL, so just because someone answered with the wrong RDBMS doesn't make it a proper duplicate IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True, I just wanted to indicate where the OP could find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will support up over 2,000 days (depending on your version of SQL Server and how many user objects you have), if you need more than that, just change `sys.all_objects` to `sys.all_columns` (which should support over 8,000).

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '20130101', @end DATE = '20130107';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end)+1) 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT [day] = rn, [date] = DATEADD(DAY, rn-1, @start)
FROM x
ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: both responses were very helpful - thank you, @jpw for pointing me to the procedure post and thank you for the answer in both that post and this, @aaronBertrand....stellar!