# How to generate insert between date start and date end in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii

I have tried repeatedly and suffered a constraint. In this case I want to create an event trigger (insert) for the start date and end date. So from the start date inputted, the second date will be inputted, till the last date. In your opinion what is the most effective way to solve it?

```
start date: 2013-12-01 will be added 365 days,
The second date : 2013-12-02,
.
.
.
.,
Date of last : 2014-01-01
$sql = 'INSERT into cek_tgl (`tanggal`) VALUES ('.$date.')';
            for($i=1;$i<365;$i++)
            $sql .= ',('.$date.')';

            $connection = Yii::app() -> db;
            $command = $connection -> createCommand($sql);
            $command -> execute();
```

thanks for the help

Comment: huh? please clarify your question, show examples. I'm assuming you mean a date range from start to end and to fill in the middle values?

Comment: Sorry, for my english is bad. Purpose of me is like to use afterSave () that contains a custom command to add a record to a table containing data first date, second date, third date, to the last date.

Comment: Please rewrite your question so it explains clearly what you expect to happen, or it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a stored procedure to do that. A trigger won't work as it's not allowed to insert value into the same table as the trigger is on.

Create a stored procedure that takes a start date as in parameter and then internally does 365 inserts.

Comment: Previously I had never made a store procedure. Where I write stored procedures?

Comment: Here is a link on how to do it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html If you've never before used stored procedures you might be happier just doing 365 calls from PHP to mysql.

Comment: thanks Andreas. Maybe like its : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates

Comment: That might be one way of doing it yes.