# Generate resultset according to report

Tags: mysql, sql, count, reporting, aggregate-functions

How do I generate the following reports using MYSQL?

My table 'reservations' looks like this:

```
id | arrival   | created.
1  | 2014-3-30 | 2014-3-1
2  | 2014-3-31 | 2014-3-2
3  | 2014-3-28 | 2014-3-2
4  | 2014-3-01 | 2014-3-1
5  | 2014-3-01 | 2014-3-1
```

I want to generate the following two aggregation reports for the "arrival" column for the whole month as shown below:

(1)

```
     arrival     | count  | total_monthly_arrivals
     2014-03-01  | 2      | 5
     2014-03-02  | 0      | 5
     2014-03-03  | 0      | 5
     ...
     2014-03-30  | 1      | 5
     2014-03-31  | 1      | 5
```

(2)

```
    January     | 5
    ...
    March       | 5
    ...
    December    | 0      | 5
```

I want these 2 result sets. It generates date according & month according report and generate result set in these form.

I tried to use group by with count in first resultset but it doesn't retrieve for a date that does not exist. Again I wanna put month condition such that I choose month. where month = '02' or something like this. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

My SQLFiddle should answer both parts of your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f130/31

This will return the arrival date with a count of how many people are coming that day and how many monthly arrivals there are

```
select distinct(r.arrival) as arrival_date,
count(r.arrival) as total_per_day,
sa.month_total as total_arrival_per_month
from reservations as r
  ,(select substr(arrival,6,2) as month,
    count(substr(arrival,6,2)) as month_total
    from reservations
    group by month) as sa
where substr(r.arrival,6,2) = sa.month
group by arrival_date,total_arrival_per_month;
```

This will return the month of the year and how many people are booked for that month and how many are arriving that month. (**Updated** with the suggestion from agrizzo.)

```
select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(substr(r.arrival,6,2), '%m')) as arrival_date,
sa.month_total as total_arrival_per_month
from reservations as r
  ,(select substr(arrival,6,2) as month,
    count(substr(arrival,6,2)) as month_total
    from reservations
    group by month) as sa
where substr(r.arrival,6,2) = sa.month
group by arrival_date,total_arrival_per_month;
```

There is however, no way for me to give you every day/month of the year without a fully qualified data set, provided by and prefilled by you. That's on you to do and provide us with.

However, you can check this thread. [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) and leverage their information with my queries to get your desired results.

Comment: You can probably shorten your code using MONTHNAME() function

Comment: It doesn't retrieve or set recordset according to non-existent dates and month. Means its just fetch out march and november. if it doesn't exist for Januray or FEB it should show count as 0. Similar logic I want for date that if record doesn't exist corresponding to certain date. It should show 0 against that date.

Comment: "There is however, no way for me to give you every day/month of the year without a fully qualified data set, provided by and prefilled by you. That's on you to do and provide us with."