# obtain missing date between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have this listing dates generated by a mysql query:

```
select * from fechas 
where date (fecha)> = '2014-06-03 'and date (fecha) <= '2014-06-13' 
order by fecha asc
```

```
2014-06-03
2014-06-04
2014-06-05
2014-06-07
2014-06-08
2014-06-09
2014-06-10
2014-06-11
2014-06-12
2014-06-13
```

I would get with a php function date 2014-06-06, is needed. 
2014-06-06 date no sign that there is no record in the db, but I'd get it, greetings

Comment: Please re-phrase your last paragraph stating clearly what you are currently getting and what is the desired output.

Comment: You need a table with all the dates. You can do a `LEFT JOIN` from that table to your query to get all the missing dates.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates?rq=1