# get the days between the dates

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

When i execute this sql code:

```
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY schdate), 
        ACCT , 
        SCHDATE AS DATES,
        NULL  AS ORS 
        FROM AMORT 
        WHERE ACCT = '0000360' AND CYCLE = '0001' AND principal <> '0.00'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ddate), 
         ACCT, 
         DDATE AS DATES,
         OR_NO AS ORS 
         FROM LEDGER 
         WHERE (ACCT = '0000360' AND CYCLE = '0001') AND (t_code = '10' OR t_code = '11' OR t_code = '12' OR t_code = '13')
     ORDER BY DATES
```

I've got this result., but how can i accomplish to have a days between dates?

```
ACCT    |     DATES |      ORS
-------------------------------------
0000360 |2014-07-26 | (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-02 | (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-05 | 011290000113
0000360 |2014-08-09 | (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-16 | (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-19 | 011290000559
```

I'd like to get the days between the dates like the illustration below..

```
ACCT    |     DATES |      ORS
-------------------------------------
======================
0000360 |2014-07-26 || (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-02 || (NULL)
======================
0000360 |2014-08-05 | 011290000113
======================
0000360 |2014-08-09 || (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-16 || (NULL)
======================
0000360 |2014-08-19 | 011290000559
```

Get the dates without ORS and count the days between that day for example:

```
ACCT    |     DATES |      ORS
-------------------------------------
======================
0000360 |2014-07-26 || (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-02 || (NULL)
======================
```

So, between 2014-07-26 and 2014-08-02 the counting days is 7

```
======================
0000360 |2014-08-09 || (NULL)
0000360 |2014-08-16 || (NULL)
======================
```

and for this 2014-08-09 and 2014-08-16 the counting days is 7

Comment: [`BETWEEN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between) is an option. See under "Related" over to the right also. One of which being http://stackoverflow.com/q/510012/

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You have this tagged `mysql`, but it doesn't have the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: im using sqlanywhere. how can i get the difference specially they are in one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

 $date1 = strtotime("2014-08-09");
 $date2 = strtotime("2010-08-16");
 $datediff = abs($date1 - $date2);
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

?>
```

The abs is there so you always get a positive outcome.

In **Mysql** use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('new_date', 'old_date');

SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-08-16','2014-08-09');
```

Comment: how to get difference between the dates if they are in one column?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can have MySQL compute some data for each row in a result set, and include that as part of the result, is to use user-defined variables.

For example, (test data):

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `date` date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `demo` (`date`) VALUES
('2014-09-09'),
('2014-09-10'),
('2014-09-12');
```

And then the query:

```
SET @date_last = '2014-08-01';
SELECT date, DATEDIFF(`date`, @date_last), (@date_last := `date`) FROM `demo`;
```

Returns

```
|2014-09-09|39|2014-09-09
|2014-09-10| 1|2014-09-10
|2014-09-12| 2|2014-09-12
```

Comment: tnx man!, but my dates comming from different tables. how can i accomplish that using union all with 2 tables