# How to retrieve sum of data form last 7 days as a separate sums

Tags: sql, mysql, date, aggregate-functions

In my CRM system I have table with leads. I would like to make a chart to see how many leads were added in last 7 days. For that purpose I need to have separete sums for every day from last week.

How to do that in MySQL?

My table called `tab_leads` it have `lead_id` (integer) and `lead_create_date` (time stamp, format: 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

So I need something like:

- Day 1 - 10
- Day 2 - 0
- Day 3 - 5
- Day 4 - 1
- Day 5 - 9
- Day 6 - 15
- Day 7 (today) - 2

Comment: What is important I need to have a seven sums.
Even if is no leads from specific day, I need to have a sum with 0.

Comment: did you find the solution for this situation??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT
    DATE(lead_create_date) AS `Date`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Leads`
FROM
    tab_leads
WHERE
    lead_create_date >=  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY
    DATE(lead_create_date)
```

The above query assumes that there are no future records and current day is counted as the 7th day.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the info. 
This works, but when in any of those day wasn't data (no new leads), I am not getting data.
I mean I need always 7 sums, even if sum=0.
Any chances to get this type of result?

Comment: Oh. I would use a table of dates (or something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/510012/87015) and left join it with the leads table.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this Mysql Query

```
SELECT * FROM tab_leads WHERE DATE(lead_create_date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(lead_create_date);
```

Comment: This works, but also it's not showing days with empty data.
I need always seven sums, even if sum=0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(ead_id) from tab_leads GROUP BY DAY(lead_create_date)
```

( or as per your requirement )

```
SELECT SUM(ead_id) from tab_leads GROUP BY DAY(lead_create_date)
```

Comment: Grouping by day will produce incorrect results. For example, all leads for Jan-1, Feb-1, Mar-1, etc will be consolidated in one row.