# Fetching count from database by days

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure:

```
id | some_foreign_id | date
1    5                 2015-09-29 23:14:23
2    5                 2015-09-29 14:13:21
3    8                 2015-09-28 22:23:12
```

For the specified `some_foreign_id` I want to return the count of rows in this table for each day from last 2 weeks. I created this:

```
SELECT DATE(t.sent_at), COUNT(*)
FROM table t
INNER JOIN sometable st ON st.some_id = t.id
INNER JOIN someOtherTable sot ON sot.someother_id = st.id
WHERE t.sent_at >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)
AND t.some_foreign_id = 5
GROUP BY DATE(t.sent_at);
```

It shows some results, but:

1. Doesn't show 0's if the day has 0 records.
2. Changing interval to -15 changes the count from the last day - don't know why.

How could I do this properly?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data.

Comment: You've got it, for id `5` it should return 2 rows for `2015-09-29`, and 0 rows for all other days from previous 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve 1., you'll need to left join to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates) and use `IFNULL()`

To solve 2. (or try to), try changing your query to this (I suggest you solve this first):

```
SELECT DATE(t.sent_at), COUNT(*)
FROM table t
INNER JOIN sometable st ON st.some_id = t.id
INNER JOIN someOtherTable sot ON sot.someother_id = st.id
WHERE DATE(t.sent_at) >= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY))
AND t.some_foreign_id = 5
GROUP BY DATE(t.sent_at);
```