# Write sql query to store alarm details for next 1 week with given user id

Tags: mysql, java

I am making a scheduler where currently I am saving details for reminder set by client with specific user id. Now I want to add a button of Repeat weekly where the alarm will be repeated for next 7 days on same time. What will be the sql query for that where it stores multiple tuples with same userId but with different dates of upcoming 7 days. This is how to storing 1 record.

```
@Transactional
public boolean addSchedulerBirthdayDetails(String userId,String birthdayDate, String birthdayTime, String birthdayReminder, String reminderType, String timezone, String schedulerNotification)
{
    try{
        Scheduler scheduler=new Scheduler();    
        scheduler.setUserid(userId);
        scheduler.setDate(birthdayDate);
        scheduler.setTime(birthdayTime);
        scheduler.setReminder(birthdayReminder);
        scheduler.setReminderType(reminderType);
        scheduler.setTimeZone(timezone);
        scheduler.setStatus(schedulerNotification);
        schedulerDao.addSchedulerBirthdayDetails(scheduler);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this (largely taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)):

```
SET @num = -1;
SELECT DATE_ADD( '2009-01-01', interval @num := @num+1 day) AS date_sequence 
FROM c_example
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
HAVING DATE_ADD('2009-01-01', interval @num day) <= '2009-01-13'
```

Result:

```
+---------------+
| date_sequence |
+---------------+
| 2009-01-01    |
| 2009-01-02    |
| 2009-01-03    |
... rest snipped...
```

Basically, this will produce as many records as there are records in your "dummy" table - in this case, c_example, or if your date overflows the end value.

p.s. welcome to the forum. Your question is very Java oriented - some might consider it off-topic. Take the tour, check out the Help Centre and read the "help us to help you" blog. These sites are a great resource, all the more so if you take the trouble to follow the guidelines.