# How to walk second by second a range of hours? MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I Have a range of hours in TIMESTAMP format.
Ex '2016-02-02 00:00:00' to '2016-02-02 00:00:05'
And i want to print
2016-02-02 00:00:00
2016-02-02 00:00:01
2016-02-02 00:00:02
2016-02-02 00:00:03
2016-02-02 00:00:04
2016-02-02 00:00:05

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to do this within the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates