# Query required cars for a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have two tables in database. 'car', 'reservation'

**table 'car' has following columns**

`id` -> primary key

`name` -> name of the car like SUV, STANDARD, ECONOMY

`count` -> Number of cars available

**table 'reservation' has following columns**

`id` -> Reservation id auto increment

`date_out` -> Reservation start date, ex: '2019-01-01 00:00:00'

`date_in` -> Reservation end date, ex: '2019-01-05 23:59:59'

`car_name` -> One of the car name from table 'car'

I want to query the database to show availability/shortage of cars of each type for a date range.

So output should be similar to this table.

<kbd>----date-----</kbd> <kbd>car_name</kbd> <kbd>availability/shortage</kbd>

<kbd>2019-01-01</kbd> <kbd>----SUV----</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>2019-01-01</kbd> <kbd>ECONOMY</kbd> <kbd>-1</kbd>

negative sign indicates shortage

positive sign indicated availability

**What I have done**

This query works only for a single date and car name specified.

```
Set @forDate = '2019-02-14';
Set @car = 'STANDARD';


Set @total_reservation = (select count(*) as total_reservation from (
select date_out, date_in, car_type from reservation 
where date_in > @forDate and date_out < @forDate
and car_type = @car
)AS t1);

select @total_reservation;

Set @car_count = (select count from car where name = @car);

select @car_count;

select @car_count - @total_reservation;
```

I am having problem in converting the query for a date range input by user.

Comment: Why don't you use `BETWEEN` to get data of specific date range.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? 8.xx or 5.xx?

Comment: MySql 8 @SalmanA

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [table of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates). In the following example I will simply type the dates:

```
SELECT datelist.dt, car.name, car.count - COUNT(reservation.id) AS available
FROM (
    SELECT '2019-02-14' AS dt UNION ALL -- check availability from date
    SELECT '2019-02-15' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-02-16' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-02-17' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-02-18' -- check availability to date
) AS datelist
CROSS JOIN car
LEFT JOIN reservation ON datelist.dt BETWEEN reservation.date_out AND reservation.date_in
      AND car.name = reservation.car_name
GROUP BY datelist.dt, car.name, car.count
```

In MySQL 8 you can use a recursive cte to build the dates:

```
WITH RECURSIVE datelist AS (
    SELECT '2019-02-14' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM datelist WHERE dt < '2019-02-18'
)
SELECT datelist.dt, car.name, car.count - COUNT(reservation.id) AS available
FROM datelist
CROSS JOIN car
LEFT JOIN reservation ON datelist.dt BETWEEN reservation.date_out AND reservation.date_in
      AND car.name = reservation.car_name
GROUP BY datelist.dt, car.name, car.count
```