# DATETIME value missing in query output then autofill that missing values and get correct output

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, codeigniter-3

When I take the data from a database with a one-second interval that time only available `DateTime` interval output count gets and missing some `DateTime` interval from the output.

I fill all missing `DateTime` intervals with count 0.

**Example:**

if **start date**: `2019-10-15 02:36:23` then

**end date** : `2019-10-15 03:36:22`

get one-hour data with one-second intervals if that time not available any count then get 0 counts.

```
mysql> select start_date,count(id) as count from live_login where start_date >= '2019-10-15 02:36:23' GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) DIV 1;
+---------------------+-------+
| start_date           | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2019-10-15 02:36:23 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:24 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:26 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:55 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:57 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:37:08 |     1 |
```

**Output need like this:**

```
| start_date           | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2019-10-15 02:36:23 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:24 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:25 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:26 |     1 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:27 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:28 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:29 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:30 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:31 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:32 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:33 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:34 |     0 |
| 2019-10-15 02:36:35 |     0 |
```

Comment: You can modify the function available in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates and join with it to get the required data.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a virtual table containing all the seconds in the appropriate range, and then join them to the summary.
Try to modify the query like this :

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS count,
        listofseconds.login_date
    FROM (
        SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq SECOND AS login_date
        FROM (
                SELECT '2019-10-15 02:36:23' AS mintime,
                (SELECT DATE_ADD('2019-10-15 02:36:23', INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE_SECOND)) AS maxtime
                FROM live_login
            ) AS minmax
        JOIN seq_0_to_999999 AS seq ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,mintime,maxtime)
        ) AS listofseconds

    LEFT JOIN live_login ON listofseconds.login_date = SECOND(live_login.start_date)
    GROUP BY SECOND(listofseconds.login_date)
    ORDER BY SECOND(listofseconds.login_date)
```

This query will get an **end_date** of `2019-10-15 03:36:22` :

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD('2019-10-15 02:36:23', INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE_SECOND)
```

This query will get the seconds in the range :

```sql
        SELECT mintime + INTERVAL seq.seq SECOND AS login_date
        FROM (
                SELECT '2019-10-15 02:36:23' AS mintime,
                (SELECT DATE_ADD('2019-10-15 02:36:23', INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE_SECOND)) AS maxtime
                FROM live_login
            ) AS minmax
        JOIN seq_0_to_999999 AS seq ON seq.seq < TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,mintime,maxtime)
```