# t-sql select query filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the below table and inputs:

```
Id  RelatedId
--------------
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   2
2   3 
2   4
3   5
```

Inputs are `@input_1 = 2 and @input_2 = 3`   (input count can vary)

I want to select only those Ids from the above table that have both these input in their corresponding RelatedIds.

So, based on the give inputs, output will be

```
Id
---
1
2
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are the inputs being passed? Is this a stored procedure? The fact that input count can vary is the trickiest problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
select id
from YourTable
where relatedid in ( @input_1, @input_2)
group by id
having count(*) >=2 -- for 3 inputs, make this 3 etc
```

example you can run

```
create table #yourtable(Id int,  RelatedId int)

insert #yourtable values(1,1)
insert #yourtable values(1,2)
insert #yourtable values(1,3)
insert #yourtable values(2,2)
insert #yourtable values(2,3)
insert #yourtable values(2,4)
insert #yourtable values(3,5)


declare @input_1 int, @input_2 int
select @input_1 = 2,@input_2 = 3

select id
from #yourtable
where relatedid in ( @input_1, @input_2)
group by id
having count(*) >=2
```

Comment: Or "count(distinct relatedid)" if there's a possibility of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id FROM tableName 
INNER JOIN (SELECT @input_1 AS id 
   UNION SELECT @input_2,
   UNION SELECT @input_3) inputs
ON inputs.id = tableName.Id
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273623/mysql-select-from-a-list-of-numbers-those-without-a-counterpart-in-the-id-field/273703#273703)

Alternatively:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @inputs TABLE( id tinyint )
  INSERT INTO @inputs SELECT @input_1
  INSERT INTO @inputs SELECT @input_2
  INSERT INTO @inputs SELECT @input_3

  SELECT * FROM tableName
  INNER JOIN @inputs i ON i.id = tableName.Id
END
```