# Return multiple semi-identical rows with specifics differences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL data like this:

```
id  date_start  date_end  identical_value
1   1           1         a
2   1           3         b
3   2           3         c
```

I need return multiple semi-identical results, but only with ID and a new column. Below an example:

```
id  date_reference  identical_value
1   1               a
2   1               b
2   2               b
2   3               b
3   2               c
3   3               c
```

Note that the column `date_reference` starts on `date_start` and end on `date_end`.

I have a good notion on basic SQL, but I don't undestand to much of loopings, and I think that maybe is essential here.

**What I need**: a good example -- not exactly the answer -- to I understand if it is possible or not, or what I need to search (functions, keyworkds...) of MySQL to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with integers from 1 to some [very large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273623/mysql-select-from-a-list-of-numbers-those-without-a-counterpart-in-the-id-field/273703#273703).  Then you can join on the number table to expand the date range:

```
select  yt.id
,       num.Number as date_reference
,       yt.identical_value
from    YourTable yt
join    NumberTable num
on      num.Number between yt.date_start and yt.date_end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use more than one table -- all useful data are on this table. And my example is hypotetical. For instance: date_start is DATE type, not a INT. I need to know how SQL loopings works for cases like that.

Comment: Ah!!! I think that I understand what you suggest. On my case, I need create a table with DATEs from TODAY to 10 YEARS AFTER, and loop this data, right? Thanks... I'll try and I will back with a result...